# jQuery one class name with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

My coding is working fine, just wondered if there is more tidy way to write jQuery code?
I was searching for this internet but cant find examples.

There are three duplicated class name with different selectors having different CSS settings. I would like to know if there is clean coding for this.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('toggle')) {


    $(".toggle > span:first").css({
        // something...
    });

    $(".toggle > span:nth-child(2)").css({
        // something...
    });

    $(".toggle > span:last").css({
        // something...
    });

}
```

Is there similar to SCSS way? Like below

```
.toggle {
    span {
        &:first-child { // something... }
        &:nth-child(2) { // something... }
        &:last-child { // something... }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking time to look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.end()`**](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
$(".toggle")
.children("span:first").css({"color":"blue"})
.end()
.children("span:nth-child(2)").css({"color": "green"})
.end()
.children("span:last").css({"color": "red"});
```

Or, use .filter()

```
$(".toggle")
.children("span")
.filter(":first").css({"color":"blue"})
.end()
.filter(":nth-child(2)").css({"color": "green"})
.end()
.filter(":last").css({"color": "red"});
```

Comment: Your solution was perfect.I think checking this question also can give a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251814/jquery-and-organized-code/255222#255222

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(this).hasClass('toggle')) {

    $('.toggle > span')
        .first().css({
            // something...
        })
        .end().eq(2).css({
            // something...
        })
        end().last().css({
            // something...
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through on them:

```
var i = 0;
$(".toggle span").each(function($obj) {
   console.log('Now i is ' + i);
   console.log($obj);
   switch (i) {
      case 0:
        //do something
        break;
        //and so on, or call a function with obj and i.
   }

   i++;
});
```

You can also add `data-id` or `data-anything` to your classes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it`s not similar.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('toggle')) {    

    $(".toggle > span:first").css({
        // something...
    });

    $(".toggle > span:nth-child(2)").css({
        // something...
    });

    $(".toggle > span:last").css({
        // something...
    });

}
```

is similar to:

```
.toggle {
    > span {
        &:first-child { // something... }
        &:nth-child(2) { // something... }
        &:last-child { // something... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to add span in it but I mean, want to know jQuery code, not SCSS. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question correctly. I didn't know beauty ways for your question. I`m trying to use additional classname to element and styling childrens with css.