# Parameter value transfer in Qt connect

Tags: qt, signals

I'm using the next line in order to display the position of the slider on the label.

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), label, SLOT(setNum(int)));
```

It works fine.
However, I don't really understand how is this value being transferred. 
How does the parameter of the *valueChanged* function pass to the *setNum* function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [signals and slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312895/signals-and-slots)

Answer (score 1):

- When you call `connect` you specify a signature of a signal and of a slot (or another signal).
- `Qt` uses these signatures to store an "internal link" between 2 methods.
- When a signal method is called (for example, with `emit valueChanged(5)`) `Qt` looks for a corresponding `slot` method in the list of "links".
- Then `Qt` calls a `slot` method passing arguments from the first `signal` method.

Read this [article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) thoroughly. It's really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the signal is triggered, it gives the `int` to the slot function. It's like if you (the slot) go and see you neighbor to give him eggs and then he do whatever he wants with it.

You can see this excellent [doc about how Qt Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) works