# JavaScript minifyer which can be integrated with a build of an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, javascript, build-automation, minify

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247209/javascript-how-do-you-organize-this-mess/248951#248951).. Can you guys point me to something similar--something that can be integrated into a build-script or perhaps directly into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link from womps post (Nick Berardi's blog post) uses the YUI Compressor for *java*. So if you don't want to have the extra dependency of java / installing java, then you can do the same thing with a .NET port of the most excellent YUI Compressor project -> [YUICompressor for .NET](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/).

Maybe that might help :)

*Disclaimer: I did most of that port.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio projects use MSBuild, so you can integrate an MSBuild task that uses whatever javascript minifier you'd like.

This has been blogged about pretty extensively so I won't bother trying to come up with the specifics here... but a quick google search yielded some good posts.

http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/05/how-to-create-a-yui-compressor-msbuild-task/

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/minify-your-javascript-and-save-the-kbs-for-later-imtech-javascript-minificator-free-tool/

Comment: Yep I've used Nick Berardi's (the CoderJournal link) in the past to include YUI Minifier in the project build scripts.