# What is the purpose of wrapping whole Javascript files in anonymous functions like “(function(){ … })()”?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I have been reading a lot of Javascript lately and I have been noticing that the whole file is wrapped like the following in the .js files to be imported.

```
(function() {
    ... 
    code
    ...
})();
```

What is the reason for doing this rather than a simple set of constructor functions?

Comment: Since I imagine this will be used by a lot of people, please don't forget the closing ;

Comment: This technic is called "IIFE" I think. This stands for Immediately Invoked Function Expression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572)

Answer (score 850, accepted):

It's usually to namespace (see later) and control the visibility of member functions and/or variables. Think of it like an object definition. The technical name for it is an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** (IIFE). jQuery plugins are usually written like this.

In Javascript, you can nest functions. So, the following is legal:

```
function outerFunction() {
   function innerFunction() {
      // code
   }
}
```

Now you can call `outerFunction()`, but the visiblity of `innerFunction()` is limited to the scope of `outerFunction()`, meaning it is private to `outerFunction()`. It basically follows the same principle as variables in Javascript:

```
var globalVariable;

function someFunction() {
   var localVariable;
}
```

Correspondingly:

```
function globalFunction() {

   var localFunction1 = function() {
       //I'm anonymous! But localFunction1 is a reference to me!
   };

   function localFunction2() {
      //I'm named!
   }
}
```

In the above scenario, you can call `globalFunction()` from anywhere, but you cannot call `localFunction1` or `localFunction2`.

What you're doing when you write `(function() { ... })()`, is you're making the code inside the first set of parentheses a function literal (meaning the whole "object" is actually a function). After that, you're self-invoking the function (the final `()`) that you just defined. So the major advantage of this as I mentioned before, is that you can have private methods/functions and properties:

```
(function() {
   var private_var;

   function private_function() {
     //code
   }
})();
```

In the first example, you would explicitly invoke `globalFunction` by name to run it. That is, you would just do `globalFunction()` to run it. But in the above example, you're not just defining a function; you're defining *and* invoking it in one go. This means that when the your JavaScript file is loaded, it is immediately executed. Of course, you could do:

```
function globalFunction() {
    // code
}
globalFunction();
```

The behavior would largely be the same except for one significant difference: you avoid polluting the global scope when you use an IIFE (as a consequence it also means that you cannot invoke the function multiple times since it doesn't have a name, but since this function is only meant to be executed once it really isn't an issue).

The neat thing with IIFEs is that you can also define things inside and only expose the parts that you want to the outside world so (an example of namespacing so you can basically create your own library/plugin):

```
var myPlugin = (function() {
 var private_var;

 function private_function() {
 }

 return {
    public_function1: function() {
    },
    public_function2: function() {
    }
 }
})()
```

Now you can call `myPlugin.public_function1()`, but you cannot access `private_function()`! So pretty similar to a class definition. To understand this better, I recommend the following links for some further reading:

- [Namespacing your Javascript](http://archive.is/yXtVK)
- [Private members in Javascript (by Douglas Crockford)](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention. In that final `()`, you can pass anything you want inside. For example, when you create jQuery plugins, you pass in `jQuery` or `$` like so:

```
(function(jQ) { ... code ... })(jQuery)
```

So what you're doing here is defining a function that takes in one parameter (called `jQ`, a local variable, and known *only* to that function). Then you're self-invoking the function and passing in a parameter (also called `jQuery`, but *this* one is from the outside world and a reference to the actual jQuery itself).  There is no pressing need to do this, but there are some advantages:

- You can redefine a global parameter and give it a name that makes sense in the local scope.
- There is a slight performance advantage since it is faster to look things up in the local scope instead of having to walk up the scope chain into the global scope.
- There are benefits for compression (minification).

Earlier I described how these functions run automatically at startup, but if they run automatically who is passing in the arguments?  This technique assumes that all the parameters you need are already defined as global variables. So if jQuery wasn't already defined as a global variable this example would not work. As you might guess, one things jquery.js does during its initialization is define a 'jQuery' global variable, as well as its more famous '$' global variable, which allows this code to work after jQuery has been included.

Comment: Very cool, I understand namespace well, but I've seen a lot of that last example of yours and couldn't figure out what people were trying to achieve. This really clears things up.

Comment: I think adding a leading and trailing semicolon ';' would make the example complete - `;(function(jQ) { ... code ... })(jQuery);` This way if someone left off a semicolon in their script it would not break yours, especially if you plan to minify and concatenate your script with other.

Comment: nice post, I like the emphasis on private variables. I also like the opening on the module-pattern/closures (public_function1 & public_function2) & how you pass variables, even though slightly getting out of scope it's a nice introduction. I also added an answer, this one focussing on what I suppose are the roots of the syntax & differences between function statement vs function expression & what I think is "just a convention" vs "the only way to achieve this result".

Comment: Great post, I think maybe more on how passing variables into the self executing function is beneficial. The context in the self executing function is clean - no data. You can pass in the context  by doing this `(function (context) { ..... })(this)` which then allows you to attach anything you like to the parent context thus exposing it.

Comment: Great post!
I'd like to add that it is also common on this environment to have an export declaration at the end of the code (sometimes it is the only executable part of this anonymous function definition). So most libraries end with an export declaration of the type `this.myLib = myLib`, `define(myLib)`, `module.exports = myLib` or a combination of these.

Comment: First link is dead

Comment: Great answer. Good note about returning publics, that's a nice explicit easy way to do that and have all public defs in one spot.  But, it's worth noting you can also just use "this.somePublicFunction = function(){};" and also achieve the same thing without needing any return function, or just a "return this" if you want to return the main object with all it's "this." functions already attached in this public way.

Comment: Great post, but I'd like to add that since module is introduced in ES6, you almost never needed IIFE anymore: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md#functions--iife

Answer (score 82):

## In short

### Summary

In its simplest form, this technique aims to wrap code inside a **function scope**.

It helps decreases chances of:

- clashing with other applications/libraries
- polluting superior (global most likely) scope

It **does not** detect when the document is ready - it is not some kind of `document.onload` nor `window.onload`

It is commonly known as an `Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)` or `Self Executing Anonymous Function`.

### Code Explained

```
var someFunction = function(){ console.log('wagwan!'); };

(function() {                   /* function scope starts here */
  console.log('start of IIFE');

  var myNumber = 4;             /* number variable declaration */
  var myFunction = function(){  /* function variable declaration */
    console.log('formidable!'); 
  };
  var myObject = {              /* object variable declaration */
    anotherNumber : 1001, 
    anotherFunc : function(){ console.log('formidable!'); }
  };
  console.log('end of IIFE');
})();                           /* function scope ends */

someFunction();            // reachable, hence works: see in the console
myFunction();              // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
myObject.anotherFunc();    // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
```

In the example above, any variable defined in the function (i.e. declared using `var`) will be "private" and accessible within the function scope ONLY (as Vivin Paliath puts it). In other words, these variables are not visible/reachable outside the function. [See live demo](http://jsbin.com/yadagusato/1/edit?js,console).

Javascript has function scoping. "Parameters and variables defined in a function are not visible outside of the function, and that a variable defined anywhere within a function is visible everywhere within the function." (from "Javascript: The Good Parts").

---

## More details

### Alternative Code

In the end, the code posted before could also be done as follows:

```
var someFunction = function(){ console.log('wagwan!'); };

var myMainFunction = function() {
  console.log('start of IIFE');

  var myNumber = 4;
  var myFunction = function(){ console.log('formidable!'); };
  var myObject = { 
    anotherNumber : 1001, 
    anotherFunc : function(){ console.log('formidable!'); }
  };
  console.log('end of IIFE');
};

myMainFunction();          // I CALL "myMainFunction" FUNCTION HERE
someFunction();            // reachable, hence works: see in the console
myFunction();              // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
myObject.anotherFunc();    // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
```

[See live demo](http://jsbin.com/yetebenula/1/edit?js,console).

---

### The Roots

#### Iteration 1

One day, someone probably thought "there must be a way to avoid naming 'myMainFunction', since all we want is to execute it immediately."

If you go back to the basics, you find out that:

- `expression`: something evaluating to a value. i.e. `3+11/x`
- `statement`: line(s) of code doing something BUT it does **not** evaluate to a value. i.e. `if(){}`

Similarly, function expressions evaluate to a value. And one consequence (I assume?) is that they can be immediately invoked:

```
 var italianSayinSomething = function(){ console.log('mamamia!'); }();
```

So our more complex example becomes:

```
var someFunction = function(){ console.log('wagwan!'); };

var myMainFunction = function() {
  console.log('start of IIFE');

  var myNumber = 4;
  var myFunction = function(){ console.log('formidable!'); };
  var myObject = { 
    anotherNumber : 1001, 
    anotherFunc : function(){ console.log('formidable!'); }
  };
  console.log('end of IIFE');
}();

someFunction();            // reachable, hence works: see in the console
myFunction();              // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
myObject.anotherFunc();    // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
```

[See live demo](http://jsbin.com/virozipike/1/edit?js,console).

#### Iteration 2

The next step is the thought "why have `var myMainFunction =` if we don't even use it!?".

The answer is simple: try removing this, such as below:

```
 function(){ console.log('mamamia!'); }();
```

[See live demo](http://jsbin.com/kefesopixi/1/edit?js,console).

It won't work because **"function declarations are not invokable"**.

The trick is that by removing `var myMainFunction =` we transformed the **function expression** into a **function declaration**. See the links in "Resources" for more details on this.

The next question is "why can't I keep it as a function expression with something other than `var myMainFunction =`?

The answer is "you can", and there are actually many ways you could do this: adding a `+`, a `!`, a `-`, or maybe wrapping in a pair of parenthesis (as it's now done by convention), and more I believe.  As example:

```
 (function(){ console.log('mamamia!'); })(); // live demo: jsbin.com/zokuwodoco/1/edit?js,console.
```

or

```
 +function(){ console.log('mamamia!'); }(); // live demo: jsbin.com/wuwipiyazi/1/edit?js,console
```

or

```
 -function(){ console.log('mamamia!'); }(); // live demo: jsbin.com/wejupaheva/1/edit?js,console
```

- [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)
- [JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name)

So once the relevant modification is added to what was once our "Alternative Code", we return to the exact same code as the one used in the "Code Explained" example

```
var someFunction = function(){ console.log('wagwan!'); };

(function() {
  console.log('start of IIFE');

  var myNumber = 4;
  var myFunction = function(){ console.log('formidable!'); };
  var myObject = { 
    anotherNumber : 1001, 
    anotherFunc : function(){ console.log('formidable!'); }
  };
  console.log('end of IIFE');
})();

someFunction();            // reachable, hence works: see in the console
myFunction();              // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
myObject.anotherFunc();    // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
```

Read more about `Expressions vs Statements`:

- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)
- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)
- [Javascript: difference between a statement and an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703214/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression)
- [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

---

### Demystifying Scopes

One thing one might wonder is "what happens when you do NOT define the variable 'properly' inside the function -- i.e. do a simple assignment instead?"

```
(function() {
  var myNumber = 4;             /* number variable declaration */
  var myFunction = function(){  /* function variable declaration */
    console.log('formidable!'); 
  };
  var myObject = {              /* object variable declaration */
    anotherNumber : 1001, 
    anotherFunc : function(){ console.log('formidable!'); }
  };
  myOtherFunction = function(){  /* oops, an assignment instead of a declaration */
    console.log('haha. got ya!');
  };
})();
myOtherFunction();         // reachable, hence works: see in the console
window.myOtherFunction();  // works in the browser, myOtherFunction is then in the global scope
myFunction();              // unreachable, will throw an error, see in the console
```

[See live demo](http://jsbin.com/pahetitafa/1/edit?js,console).

Basically, if a variable that was not declared in its current scope is assigned a value, then "a look up the scope chain occurs until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it)".

When in a browser environment (vs a server environment like nodejs) the global scope is defined by the `window` object. Hence we can do `window.myOtherFunction()`.

My "Good practices" tip on this topic is to **always use `var` when defining anything**: whether it's a number, object or function, & even when in the global scope. This makes the code much simpler.

Note:

- javascript does **not** have `block scope` (Update: block scope local variables added in [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).)
- javascript has only `function scope` & `global scope` (`window` scope in a browser environment)

Read more about `Javascript Scopes`:

- [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)
- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

---

## Resources

- [youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=2m15s](http://youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=2m15s) - Paul Irish presents the IIFE at min 2:15, do watch this!
- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [Book: Javascript, the good parts](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20the%20good%20parts) - highly recommended
- [youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=4m36s](http://youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=4m36s) - Paul Irish presents the module pattern at 4:36

---

## Next Steps

Once you get this `IIFE` concept, it leads to the `module pattern`, which is commonly done by leveraging this IIFE pattern. Have fun :)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, I prefer the **demo** version :)

Comment: Such a great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

Javascript in a browser only really has a couple of effective scopes: function scope and global scope.

If a variable isn't in function scope, it's in global scope. And global variables are generally bad, so this is a construct to keep a library's variables to itself.

Comment: But doesn't the constructor function itself provides scope for its own variables?

Comment: Yes, each function defined in this library could define its own local variables, but this allows variables to be shared between the functions without them leaking outside of the library

Comment: @Gareth, so this allows for "global" variables within a scope (;

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia "global within a scope" isn't a useful phrase, because that's basically just what "scope" means. The whole point of the "global" scope is that it's specifically the scope that *all* other scopes have access to.

Answer (score 20):

That's called a closure. It basically seals the code inside the function so that other libraries don't interfere with it. It's similar to creating a namespace in compiled languages.

Example. Suppose I write:

```
(function() {

    var x = 2;

    // do stuff with x

})();
```

Now other libraries cannot access the variable `x` I created to use in my library.

Comment: Careful with your terminology. Namespacing implies that the variables can be accessed from outside by addressing the namespace (typically by using a prefix). While this is possible in Javascript that isn't what's demonstrated here

Comment: I agree it is not exactly like a namespace, however, you can provide similar functionality by returning an object with properties which you want to publicize: `(function(){ ... return { publicProp1: 'blah' }; })();`. Obviously not perfectly parallel to namespacing, but it may help to think of it that way.

Comment: in your example x is still a private variable... Despite you wrapping it in a IIFE.  go ahead and try to access x outside of the function, you can't..

Comment: Your point is not valid.  Even in the following function other libraries can't access x.   function() {
    var x = 2
}

Comment: @RayLoveless I agree. I do not contradict that assertion. In fact, I made the same assertion as the last sentence of this answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use function closures as **data** in larger expressions as well, as in this method of determining browser support for some of the html5 objects.

```
   navigator.html5={
     canvas: (function(){
      var dc= document.createElement('canvas');
      if(!dc.getContext) return 0;
      var c= dc.getContext('2d');
      return typeof c.fillText== 'function'? 2: 1;
     })(),
     localStorage: (function(){
      return !!window.localStorage;
     })(),
     webworkers: (function(){
      return !!window.Worker;
     })(),
     offline: (function(){
      return !!window.applicationCache;
     })()
    }
```

Comment: What does the !! do?

Comment: !! converts a value to it's boolean (true/false) representation.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to keeping the variables local, one very handy use is when writing a library using a global variable, you can give it a shorter variable name to use within the library. It's often used in writing jQuery plugins, since jQuery allows you to disable the $ variable pointing to jQuery, using jQuery.noConflict(). In case it is disabled, your code can still use $ and not break if you just do:

```
(function($) { ...code...})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. To avoid clash with other methods/libraries in the same window,
2. Avoid Global scope, make it local scope,
3. To make debugging faster (local scope),
4. JavaScript has function scope only, so it will help in compilation of codes as well.

Answer (score 1):

We should also use 'use strict' in the scope function to make sure that the code should be executed in "strict mode". Sample code shown below

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //Your code from here
})();
```

Comment: Why should we use strict?

Comment: Check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: Does not really answer the question!

Comment: Pritam, its a good practice use. Please do proper research before voting down any answer

Comment: 'use strict' saves bad programmers from themselves.  And since the majority of programmers are bad programmers, it helps prevent them from doing things they definitely should not be doing and ending up in a quickly sinking mess of code.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an example for the accepted answer, from https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html:

```
(function () {
    var $ = this.jQuery;

    this.myExample = function () {};
}());
```

The code demonstrates that we can:

1. use global variables inside the scope
2. export functions, variables etc.. by binding on `this`, which is the `window` object as for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Its called [encapsulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Encapsulation) in OOP.