# jQuery's function($) (jQuery) syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/jquery-what-does-function-jquery-mean)

I stumbled up on the following code (included in one file) but I just cannot understand what it really means.

```
(function ($) {
    function doSomething1(somedata) {

    }

    function doSomething1(somedata) {

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Question 1:
What does this syntax mean in the contex of jQuery

Question 2:
How can we call these functions let say from other files such as the HTML index file and other JavaScript files?

Thanks

Comment: it is a self executing anonymous function. Go through this post http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/

Comment: This question has been asked many times previously

Comment: @Russ Cam: It's just too bad it's made up of a bunch of symbols, which is pretty hard to search SO or Google for...

Comment: The symbols do make it harder to search, but there are still so many, they're easy to find. For example, put this into google `site:stackoverflow.com what does (function($) { mean jQuery` (the url doesn't come out as and anchor link if I pasted directly)

Answer (score 8):

This syntax is not particularly special to jquery, it's normal javascript. Here simply function

```
function ($) {
    // some code here...
}
```

(note that it takes argument named `$`) is called with parameter `jQuery` (which is, obviously, global object of jQuery framework).

This is usually done when there're several js frameworks on one page (jquery, dojo, prototype, etc) which all redefine global variable `$`. But with this code, inside `doSomething1` or `doSomething2` you can always call `$('.test')` and be certain that call will be processed by jquery, not dojo. Because `$` is not a global variable in this case, it's function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question here, but the (function() means it's self-executing,

and you call them by importing the files in the main page and then calling

doSomething1()

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely that was jQuery plugin: [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)