# What does $(function ()..})(jQuery); mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/jquery-what-does-function-jquery-mean)

I am using the Telerik MVC controls.  In the `telerik.examples.min.js` file they have the following:

```
$(function () {
   // other code here
})(jQuery);
```

Has this only got to do with global variables?  If so, why are global variables bad?

What is `(jQuery)`?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? The function call seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes the file starts and end with these lines, but in between there are many lines of code.  This is from the latest version of the controls.  Is it incorrect?

Comment: Oops no it is not, sorry this is for something else.  Sorry my mistake.