# Masking phone number using TextBoxFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mask

I want to mask a phone number using  html helpers  (TextBoxFor)

there is my  code

```
  Model :
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = 
         typeof(ProcRec.Ressources.Candidat.ErreurValidation),
         ErrorMessageResourceName = "num_tel_obligatoire")]
         [RegularExpression(@"[0][6]\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$",
        ErrorMessageResourceType =   
        typeof(ProcRec.Ressources.Candidat.ErreurValidation),
         ErrorMessageResourceName = "num_tel_faux")]   
         public string num_tel { set; get; }
```

View  :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
       $("#num_tel").mask("(999) 999-9999");
       $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
       $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
      });

        </script>

       <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.num_tel)</td>
       <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.num_tel)</td>
```

the validation is working

but when it comes to mask  i get nothing

their is  the result i get

[image: http://postimg.org/image/gm1ygs6fn/]

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Just havea look to http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: i tried that but it's not working whith textboxfor... i think i'm missing somthing but i dont know where

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: try to put the javascript code inside `$(document).ready(function(){/* put here */});`

Comment: `jQuery(function($){ ....});` should be like `(function($){...})(jQuery);`... I am not sure but I have seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean) link.

Comment: BhushanKawadkar   no it's working just like the mask is not exist..........

YuliamChandra   i tried that, stil have nothing

Comment: i found the solution  check the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
The problem was that I have not installed  `jQuery.MaskedInput` plugin.

To install `jQuery.MaskedInput`, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.MaskedInput -Version 1.3.1
```