# What does the following code mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What does the following code mean in JavaScript :

```
(function() {

})();
```

Comment: its a syntax for creating new function.

Comment: Declartion of an anonymous function that is executed as soon as it is defined?!

Comment: please gothrough this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean,  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

Thats a **singleton/IIFE** (immediately invoked function expression).

Using an IIFE can be helpful when wanting to use a local scope which eliminates binding to global objects like the window.

There is also a slight performance benefit to this approach as you can pass in commonly used objects to the anonymous function. JavaScript first looks for a property in its local scope then works up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Self-Invoking Anonymous Function**.

> A self-invoking anonymous runs automatically/immediately when you create it and has no name, hence called anonymous.

[**More info**](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

Comment: It's not self-invoking (the code calling it is not part of the function). It *is* immediately-invoked. The standard term is IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).