# ajax url showing undefined on console logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to pull some content with ajax and at my first step i have fallen wrong .

### Here is my simple code

`<a href="page.php" data-content="ajax"</a>`

### and my js is

```
(function($){

    'use strict';

     var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
         ajaxUrl;

     ajaxcontent.each(function(index, el) {
         var ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');
     });

     console.log(ajaxUrl);

})(jQuery);
```

but it shows `undefined` in console.

### I have also tried with --

`<a href="" data-content="ajax" data-url="page.php"></a>`

```
(function($){

    'use strict';

     var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
         ajaxUrl;

     ajaxcontent.each(function(index, el) {
         var ajaxUrl = $(this).data('url');
     });

     console.log(ajaxUrl);

})(jQuery);
```

result is same  .

Comment: You can try this.. `var ajaxUrl=el.getAttribute('href')` http://jsfiddle.net/scdbfduk/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var` inside the callback function otherwise it act as a local variable

```js
(function($){

    'use strict';

     var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
         ajaxUrl;

     ajaxcontent.each(function(index, el) {
         ajaxUrl = $(this).data('url');
     });

     console.log(ajaxUrl);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" data-content="ajax" data-url="page.php"></a>
```

Also value of ajaxUrl will be the `href` attribute value of last item with the selector. So if there is only one item then use the following

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var ajaxUrl = $('[data-content="ajax"]').data('url');
  console.log(ajaxUrl);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" data-content="ajax" data-url="page.php"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean)

Then you can see that `(function(){})()` is mealy a function that is executed in place.

it means that if you have your `<a>` tag before this script in your page, your code will work and if your `<a>` tag is after your script, it will return `undefined` because at the moment your `script` is running, there is no such element in your `DOM`

So the best way to achieve what you want is to use `$(document).ready(function(){` or the shorter method `$(function(){`

So your script will look like this:

```
$(function(){
   'use strict';

     var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
         ajaxUrl;

     ajaxcontent.each(function(index, el) {
         ajaxUrl = $(this).data('url');
     });

     console.log(ajaxUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below fiddle works. Remember to use the callback after the dom element else the element wont be inserted, else use ready function as shown.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    (function($){

        'use strict';

         var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
             ajaxUrl;

         ajaxcontent.each(function() {
             ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');
             console.log('each is ' + ajaxUrl);
         });

         console.log('last one is' + ajaxUrl);

    })(jQuery);
});


<a href="page.php" class="a" data-content="ajax"></a>
<a href="page2.php" class="a" data-content="ajax"></a>
<a href="page3.php" class="a" data-content="ajax"></a>
<a href="page4.php" class="a" data-content="ajax"></a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8nfvn8u/3/)