# bootstrap not working in html block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to implement bootstrap in drupal I have the 'row'  class for contact id. and added col-sm-12 for for title and desc but working.I takes the with od the container.I am doing accordian.js works fine.css for bootstrap not working

```js
(function ($)
 {
 function contactList(){
 $('.view-content .contactDesc:first').css('display','block');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first , .view-content .contactDesc:first').addClass('active');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first .glyphicon').addClass('rotate');
 $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
    $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
 $('.contactTitle .glyphicon ').removeClass('rotate');
 $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
   $('.contactDesc').removeClass('active');
   $(this).next('.contactDesc').addClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.officeAddress .colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
     });
 }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  contactList();
  });
 });
```

```css
.contactForm{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 59px;
}
.contactForm img{
 width: 960px;
 height: auto;
}
.officeAddress{
  width:960px;margin:0 auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
 }
.contactTitle{
 width:960px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 18px 40px 18px 40px;
 font-size:20px;
 }
.contactDesc{
 display:none;
 font-size:23px;
 padding: 40px 0 0px 0;
 font-family: Raleway-Regular;
 }
.ContactAddressHeading p,.currentOpening{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000000;
 padding: 38px 0px 0px 0;
 text-align: center;
 } 
  
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
} 
.container-fluid{
 padding:0 !important;
} 
.officeAddress .purple{
  background:#663399;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.contentWidth .purple,.contentWidth .purple p{color:#ffffff;}
.purple .glyphicon{
 color:#5d218b;
}
.grey{
  background:#f7f7f7;
  color:#6c2a9f;
}
.grey .glyphicon{color:#e2dfdf;}
.purple .row-1-col-1,.purple .row-1-col-1-right,.purple .col-email a,.purple p{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.grey .col-email a{
 color:#000000;
}
.contactTitle.purple{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.contactTitle h3{
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
}

.contactTitle .glyphicon{float: right;top: 6px;} 
.form_image{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 85px;
}
.form_image img{
 width: 960px;
 height: auto; 
}
#ContactAddressHeading { margin-bottom: 55px;}
#contact{ margin-bottom: 60px;}
.officeAddress{width:960px;}
.contactDesc {display: none;font-size: 18px;}
.col-img { margin-bottom:10px; }
.row-1-col-1 { float:left; padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}
.row-1-col-1-right { min-height: 250px;float:right; padding: 0px 40px 0px 0;}
.addressImg{float:left;}
.col-address,.col-tele,.col-email{padding-left: 15px;float:left;}
.col-address span{font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;font-size: 14px;}
.address, .tele , .email{display:inline-block;}
.row-1-col-1-right .tele{
 width: 100%;
}
.address{padding-bottom: 5px;}
.grey .row-1-col-1,.grey .row-1-col-1-right,.grey .row-1-col-1 p,.grey .row-1-col-1-right p{color:#000000;}
.col-email p,.col-email div,.col-tele p,.col-tele div{display:inline;}
.contactDesc  .views-row{padding-bottom:40px;}
.col-address div p {font-size: 14px;font-family: Raleway-Regular;margin: 0 0 1px;}
@media(min-width:0px)and (max-width:780px){
 
 .row-1-col-1-right{
  float:left;
  padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
  min-height:250px;
 }
 .row-1-col-1{padding:0;}
 .contactDesc{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
 }
 .address{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
 }
 .ContactAddressHeading p{
  width:auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 0;
 }
 #ContactAddressHeading{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
 }
 #contactForm{
  display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact" class="row">
 <div class="view view-contact view-id-contact view-display-id-block view-dom-id-afcbc0b58ed02301ac5efcccfc9ea312">
  <div class="view-content">
   <div class="officeAddress">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 active purple">
     <h3>Chennai -India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right rotate"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme active grey" style="display: block;">
     <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
      <!--</div></div> -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1-right views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
      <!--</div></div> -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     </div>
     <!-- </div>  -->
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="officeAddress">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 purple">
     <h3>Hyderabad - India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme">
     <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Have you include the Jquery script before including the bootstrap script? Bootstrap need jquery.js to work. (I don't see the include of the jquery.js in the html file)

Answer (score 0):

Please add jquery before the bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this function:

```
    (function ($)
            ......
    })
```

Change it to:

```
    (function ($)
            ......
    })(jQuery);
```

For more details you can take a look to [What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean)

Working snippet:

```js
(function ($)
{
    function contactList(){
        $('.view-content .contactDesc:first').css('display','block');
        $('.view-content .contactTitle:first , .view-content .contactDesc:first').addClass('active');
        $('.view-content .contactTitle:first .glyphicon').addClass('rotate');
        $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
        $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
        $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
                $('.contactTitle .glyphicon ').removeClass('rotate');
                $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
                $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
                $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
                $('.contactDesc').removeClass('active');
                $(this).next('.contactDesc').addClass('active');
                $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
                    $('.officeAddress .colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
                    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
                    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
                });
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        contactList();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.contactForm{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 59px;
}
.contactForm img{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}
.officeAddress{
    width:960px;margin:0 auto;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
.contactTitle{
    width:960px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 18px 40px 18px 40px;
    font-size:20px;
}
.contactDesc{
    display:none;
    font-size:23px;
    padding: 40px 0 0px 0;
    font-family: Raleway-Regular;
}
.ContactAddressHeading p,.currentOpening{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#000000;
    padding: 38px 0px 0px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.container-fluid{
    padding:0 !important;
}
.officeAddress .purple{
    background:#663399;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.contentWidth .purple,.contentWidth .purple p{color:#ffffff;}
.purple .glyphicon{
    color:#5d218b;
}
.grey{
    background:#f7f7f7;
    color:#6c2a9f;
}
.grey .glyphicon{color:#e2dfdf;}
.purple .row-1-col-1,.purple .row-1-col-1-right,.purple .col-email a,.purple p{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.grey .col-email a{
    color:#000000;
}
.contactTitle.purple{
    color:#ffffff;
}
.contactTitle h3{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Raleway-Medium;
}

.contactTitle .glyphicon{float: right;top: 6px;}
.form_image{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 85px;
}
.form_image img{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}
#ContactAddressHeading { margin-bottom: 55px;}
#contact{ margin-bottom: 60px;}
.officeAddress{width:960px;}
.contactDesc {display: none;font-size: 18px;}
.col-img { margin-bottom:10px; }
.row-1-col-1 { float:left; padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}
.row-1-col-1-right { min-height: 250px;float:right; padding: 0px 40px 0px 0;}
.addressImg{float:left;}
.col-address,.col-tele,.col-email{padding-left: 15px;float:left;}
.col-address span{font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;font-size: 14px;}
.address, .tele , .email{display:inline-block;}
.row-1-col-1-right .tele{
    width: 100%;
}
.address{padding-bottom: 5px;}
.grey .row-1-col-1,.grey .row-1-col-1-right,.grey .row-1-col-1 p,.grey .row-1-col-1-right p{color:#000000;}
.col-email p,.col-email div,.col-tele p,.col-tele div{display:inline;}
.contactDesc  .views-row{padding-bottom:40px;}
.col-address div p {font-size: 14px;font-family: Raleway-Regular;margin: 0 0 1px;}
@media(min-width:0px)and (max-width:780px){

    .row-1-col-1-right{
        float:left;
        padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
        min-height:250px;
    }
    .row-1-col-1{padding:0;}
    .contactDesc{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    .address{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    .ContactAddressHeading p{
        width:auto;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 25px 0px 0px 0;
    }
    #ContactAddressHeading{
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    #contactForm{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="contact" class="row">
    <div class="view view-contact view-id-contact view-display-id-block view-dom-id-afcbc0b58ed02301ac5efcccfc9ea312">
        <div class="view-content">
            <div class="officeAddress">
                <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 active purple">
                    <h3>Chennai -India</h3>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right rotate"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme active grey" style="display: block;">
                    <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
                        <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
                        <div class="address"></div>
                        <div class="tele"></div>
                        <div class="contactMail"></div>
                        <!--</div></div> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1-right views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
                        <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
                        <div class="address"></div>
                        <div class="tele"></div>
                        <div class="contactMail"></div>
                        <!--</div></div> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last">
                        <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
                        <div class="address"></div>
                        <div class="tele"></div>
                        <div class="contactMail"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- </div>  -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="officeAddress">
                <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 purple">
                    <h3>Hyderabad - India</h3>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme">
                    <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                        <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
                        <div class="address"></div>
                        <div class="tele"></div>
                        <div class="contactMail"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still having responsive issue

Comment: @user3386779 I'm sorry, but I don't understand **responsive issue**. Could you clarify with a fiddle? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my comment, you must put the jquery.js **before** including the bootstrap script and style.

```js
(function ($)
 {
 function contactList(){
 $('.view-content .contactDesc:first').css('display','block');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first , .view-content .contactDesc:first').addClass('active');
 $('.view-content .contactTitle:first .glyphicon').addClass('rotate');
 $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
    $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
    $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
 $('.contactTitle .glyphicon ').removeClass('rotate');
 $(this).find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate');
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
   $('.contactDesc').removeClass('active');
   $(this).next('.contactDesc').addClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.officeAddress .colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:odd').addClass('grey');
          $('.officeAddress .colorme:visible:even').addClass('purple');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
     });
 }
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  contactList();
  });
 });
```

```css
.contactForm{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 59px;
}
.contactForm img{
 width: 960px;
 height: auto;
}
.officeAddress{
  width:960px;margin:0 auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
 }
.contactTitle{
 width:960px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 18px 40px 18px 40px;
 font-size:20px;
 }
.contactDesc{
 display:none;
 font-size:23px;
 padding: 40px 0 0px 0;
 font-family: Raleway-Regular;
 }
.ContactAddressHeading p,.currentOpening{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#000000;
 padding: 38px 0px 0px 0;
 text-align: center;
 } 
  
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
} 
.container-fluid{
 padding:0 !important;
} 
.officeAddress .purple{
  background:#663399;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.contentWidth .purple,.contentWidth .purple p{color:#ffffff;}
.purple .glyphicon{
 color:#5d218b;
}
.grey{
  background:#f7f7f7;
  color:#6c2a9f;
}
.grey .glyphicon{color:#e2dfdf;}
.purple .row-1-col-1,.purple .row-1-col-1-right,.purple .col-email a,.purple p{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.grey .col-email a{
 color:#000000;
}
.contactTitle.purple{
 color:#ffffff;
}
.contactTitle h3{
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
}

.contactTitle .glyphicon{float: right;top: 6px;} 
.form_image{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 85px;
}
.form_image img{
 width: 960px;
 height: auto; 
}
#ContactAddressHeading { margin-bottom: 55px;}
#contact{ margin-bottom: 60px;}
.officeAddress{width:960px;}
.contactDesc {display: none;font-size: 18px;}
.col-img { margin-bottom:10px; }
.row-1-col-1 { float:left; padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;}
.row-1-col-1-right { min-height: 250px;float:right; padding: 0px 40px 0px 0;}
.addressImg{float:left;}
.col-address,.col-tele,.col-email{padding-left: 15px;float:left;}
.col-address span{font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;font-size: 14px;}
.address, .tele , .email{display:inline-block;}
.row-1-col-1-right .tele{
 width: 100%;
}
.address{padding-bottom: 5px;}
.grey .row-1-col-1,.grey .row-1-col-1-right,.grey .row-1-col-1 p,.grey .row-1-col-1-right p{color:#000000;}
.col-email p,.col-email div,.col-tele p,.col-tele div{display:inline;}
.contactDesc  .views-row{padding-bottom:40px;}
.col-address div p {font-size: 14px;font-family: Raleway-Regular;margin: 0 0 1px;}
@media(min-width:0px)and (max-width:780px){
 
 .row-1-col-1-right{
  float:left;
  padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
  min-height:250px;
 }
 .row-1-col-1{padding:0;}
 .contactDesc{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
 }
 .address{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
 }
 .ContactAddressHeading p{
  width:auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 0;
 }
 #ContactAddressHeading{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
 }
 #contactForm{
  display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact" class="row">
 <div class="view view-contact view-id-contact view-display-id-block view-dom-id-afcbc0b58ed02301ac5efcccfc9ea312">
  <div class="view-content">
   <div class="officeAddress">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 active purple">
     <h3>Chennai -India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right rotate"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme active grey" style="display: block;">
     <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
      <!--</div></div> -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1-right views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
      <!--</div></div> -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     </div>
     <!-- </div>  -->
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="officeAddress">
    <div class="contactTitle colorme col-sm-12 col-md-12 purple">
     <h3>Hyderabad - India</h3>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="contactDesc col-sm-12 col-md-12 colorme">
     <!-- <div class="contentWidth col-md-12 col-sm-12"> -->
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-1-col-1 views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <!--<div class="contentWidth"><div class="row-1-col-1"> -->
      <div class="address"></div>
      <div class="tele"></div>
      <div class="contactMail"></div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: still having responsive issue