# What does "+" means in +function($)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I had look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean) to know about what this means.

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

I am looking at different bootstrap plugins, which have `+function ($)`, while defining the function.

What does `+` does here, does it appends this function to other functions ?

Comment: Sometimes its very hard to find the same question, my apologies @James.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To guide the javascript parser, that the thing written near the unary operator + is an expression.

EDIT: You can create javascript functions anonymously. This is one of the syntaxes to create the same. By doing so, when they are called (i.e evaluated), they act like a returning a function value. You can read more from the second link which provides a good description of it.

[This link explains it well](https://abdulapopoola.com/2014/04/03/defining-javascript-functions/)

Once declared, if not named, these can be executed inline like IIFE ([Immediately invoked function expressions](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression-a0ed32b66c18)) as well. And in this form, they can then be [used to create plugins](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin) or [used as namespaces](https://www.trainingconnection.com/javascript/lessons/invoked2.php) and attached to window object or jquery object for use later.

[Good sample file to see anonymous function code in action](https://gist.github.com/stormwild/4238330)

http://www.programering.com/a/MTMwITMwATk.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you add more details.

Comment: @bhansa added more details

Answer (score 1):

It's a `bang function`

the `+` operator is faster than usual `!`

see more at 
[javascript function leading bang ! syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax)