# Does this $ need to be replaced by jQuery on a Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've inherited a client website, and I am not a jQuery developer.

The theme `header.php` contains the following inline JavaScript:

```
(function($){
  // code here
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // code here
});
```

Do the two occurrences of the code `function($)` need to be changed to `function(jQuery)`?

Comment: `$` is alias for `jQuery`. Is your code working? If yes - no need to change. If no - you need to change code.

Comment: it passed as a parameter(alias) so that you can use `$` inside without any problem instead of writing `jQuery` again and again

Comment: Possible duplicates of:- [What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean)

Comment: `$` is not an alias of `jQuery` in Wordpress, because jQuery runs in no conflict mode there. So what you probably mean is, you make `$` an alias there. ;) @Justinas

Comment: @eisbehr oh, didn't know that in WP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No it does not** and **is not recommended to change that**

By default when you enqueue/execute a jQuery script in Wordpress you must use `jQuery`, and `$` is not used, because `$` is for compatibility with other  3rd party jQuery libraries.

You better see this [article](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Comment: `(function($){  // code here})(jQuery);` wraps jQuery into `$` **in the scope of the closure** here. So there is no harm in using `$` inside of the closure. It does not affect the outer scope as the alias is confined to inside the closure.

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)