# ! preceding function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I saw a function formatted like this today for the first time:

```
!function(){}();
```

What is the preceding exclamation mark for? I assume it functions the same as:

```
(function(){})();
```

But... what's going on here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The preceding `!` takes the un-parseable statement, and allows it to to be parsed by the JS engine, which in turn returns true.

```
function(){}();
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

!function(){}();
>>true
```

Comment: This is so misleading, it doesn't make anything parseable, it makes a function declaration be parsed as an expression, that evaluates to the function itself, allowing it to be called.

Comment: I actually think "unparseable" is accurate - the js vm will not parse the first example.

Comment: @JeffHykin Your comment is interesting and entertaining. I will, however, point out that it should say "unary" ;)

Comment: To add some clarity (adding to @michelpm's point) both `+function(){}();` and `-function(){}();` also work because `+` and `-` can be unary operators. However `!` is preferable since it is only a unary operator, while + and - can be both binary and unary operators.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing on my part, thank you @[valid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467307/valid). It's a shame Stack Overflow doesn't let comments be edited after 5 min. That one was worth deleting and fixing.

Answer (score 14):

It simply makes the JavaScript parser parse it as an expression, which is necessary to execute it.

Comment: That may be the motivation.  But the resulting expression still behaves as any expression with `!` does.

Comment: @Matthew: I can't speak for gaoshan88, but it looks like he's interested in the motivation, since he compared it (correctly) to another common way of writing self-executing functions.

Answer (score 13):

I've tried it, it returned true.
The function returns `undefined`, and `!undefined` is true.

```
!function(){}();
^          ^ ^
C          A  B
```

- A. `function(){}` is an empty anonymous function
- B. `()` executes the function (A), returning `undefined`
- C. `!` negates `undefined`, which becomes `true`

I think they used that trick for a code golf or an obfuscated code. It is a bad practice to practially use that

Try `javascript:alert(!function(){}())` in your browser address bar