# List of all binary operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

I am trying to understand what is possible with binary operators (only binary operators) in JavaScript. So far the list of binary operators I have discovered are the the following. They are primarily sourced from [this list](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_unary_operators_in_javascript), but are any missing?

Note, I am after specifically only **binary** operators which, according to the source listed above, is defined as binary operators you use with two objects (is this accurate?). I have also added the additions from @zessx.

```
+   //Add
-   //Subtract
/   //Divided by
*   //Multiple
%   //Modulus
<   //Less than
>   //Greater than
&   //AND
|   //OR
^   //XOR
~   //Invert each bits
<<  //Move all bits onto the left
>>  //Move all bits onto the right
>>> //Move all bits onto the right and fill left end with 0
```

Comment: there are also binary operator for bit, like '|' (or) and '&' for and.

Comment: first result on google: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html

Comment: this seems to be a video guide of all operators: http://bateru.com/news/2011/03/javascript-binary-operations-the-easy-way/

Comment: This seems like a good link to me. http://bit.ly/SApOip

Comment: Really not sure why this is getting down voted. I am sure it is for a good reason, but I am really not sure why.

Comment: @u1sonderzug Because this information is so prevalent on the internet. Just google it.

Comment: I understand finding lists of operators on Google, etc is relatively straight forward but I am specifically trying to understand which one of them are binary operators. It's just a term I learnt recently so still working out what precisely a binary operator is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will find a complete list in the [specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), in the expression chapter. Because the most "normal" operators are binary (see the [definition at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operator)), they are not explicitly listed as such (like the unary and ternary operators). They are:

- Multiplicative Operators

  - The `*` Operator
  - The `/` Operator
  - The `%` Operator
- Additive Operators

  - The Addition operator (`+`)
  - The Subtraction Operator (`-`)
- Bitwise Shift Operators

  - The Left Shift Operator (`<<`)
  - The Signed Right Shift Operator (`>>`)
  - The Unsigned Right Shift Operator (`>>>`)
- Relational Operators

  - The Less-than Operator (`<`)
  - The Greater-than Operator (`>`)
  - The Less-than-or-equal Operator (`<=`)
  - The Greater-than-or-equal Operator (`>=`)
  - The `instanceof` operator
  - The `in` operator
- Equality Operators

  - The Equals Operator (`==`)
  - The Does-not-equals Operator (`!=`)
  - The Strict Equals Operator (`===`)
  - The Strict Does-not-equal Operator (`!==`)
- Binary Bitwise Operators (`&`, `^`, `|`)
- Binary Logical Operators (`&&`, `||`)

Technically speaking, also the assignment and comma operators are binary.

Answer (score 11):

There are the following arithmetic operators supported by the JavaScript language.

Assume variable A holds 10 and variable B holds 20 then:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_operators.htm)*** is the original page link.

Comment: The conditional expression (also called "*the* ternary operator") is *not* a binary operator.

Comment: @Bergi The question was modified after this post. Originally it was talking about all operators.

Comment: OK, but then you forgot all those unary operators like `!` or `new`…

Answer (score 1):

```
+   //Add
-   //Subtract
/   //Divided By
*   //Multiple
%   //Modulus
<   //Less than
>   //Greater than
!   //Not
&   //And
|   //Or
^   //Xor
~   //Invert each bits
<<  //Move all bits onto the left
>>  //Move all bits onto the right
>>> //Move all bits onto the right and fill left end with 0
```