# Why is the answer 42?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how this palindrome expression is giving 42. I know about operator precedence rules, but this is beyond my current Javascript level. How can I start?

```
alert ("The answer is " +

[(0>>(0==0))+([0]+[(0==0)+(0==0)]^0)]*[(0^[(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0)]

);
```

Comment: Start by opening your JavaScript console and seeing what `true + true` evaluates to.

Comment: If you know about operator precedence, then you can rewrite this into multiple lines and follow it one operation at a time.

Comment: `Why is the answer 42?` I've got a working program to find out what the question is, but it's taking quite a long time to run...

Comment: Also.  This is not code.  Do not write code like this.  If you're maintaining code that was written like this, rewrite it.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - Your `s/exe/js/g` edit made me laugh.

Comment: @admdrew It seemed only appropriate :)

Comment: Also, I can't resist posting [google's thoughts on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=+Answer+to+the+Ultimate+Question+of+Life%2C+the+Universe%2C+and+Everything).

Comment: Similar questions with good explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4170978/218196

Comment: You're really not going to like it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic elements are as follows:

```
0==0
```

This is `true`, which can be coerced in to `1`.

```
a >> b
```

The right-shift operator. In this case, it's only used at the beginning of the expression as `0 >> 1` which evaluates to `0`.

```
a^b
```

Bitwise XOR. Both usages above have either `a` or `b` are `0`, and so the result is the non-zero operand, coerced into an integer.

```
[a] + [b]
```

String addition of `a` and `b`, evaluates to `"ab"`; if both `a` and `b` are numeric (e.g. `[0]+[1]` the result can be coerced into a numeric.

```
[a] * [b]
```

Multiplication can be performed on single element arrays, apparently. So this is equivalent to `a*b`.

Finally,

```
a << b
```

The left-shift operator; for positive integers this effectively multiplies by 2 to the power of `b`. In the expression above, this is used with `b = 0`, so the result is `a`, coerced into an integer.

If you apply the correct order of operations, you get out `[2] * [21]` which evaluates to `42`.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe, that in this case Bitwise XOR is used to cast string into number type.

Answer (score 11):

`[(0>>(0==0))+([0]+[(0==0)+(0==0)]^0)]*[(0^[(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0)] === 42` because

- `(0>>(0==0))+([0]+[(0==0)+(0==0)]^0) === 2` because

  - `(0>>(0==0)) === 0` because

    - `(0==0) === true`
    - `(0>>true) === 0` (`true` coerced into `1`)
  - `([0]+[(0==0)+(0==0)]^0) === 2` because

    - `(0==0)+(0==0) === 2`
    - `[0]+[2] === '02'`
    - `'02'^0 === 2` (`'02'` coerced into `2`)
- `(0^[(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0])+((0==0)<<0) === 21` because

  - `(0^[(0==0)+(0==0)]+[0]) === 20` because

    - `(0==0)+(0==0) === 2`
    - `[2]+[0] === '20'`
    - `0^'20' === 20`  (`'20'` coerced into `20`)
  - `((0==0)<<0) === 1` because

    - `(0==0) === true`
    - `true<<0 === 1` (`true` coerced into `1`)

The code uses three binary operators:

- `>>` is the Bitwise Right Shift with Sign Operator:

  > It moves all bits in its first operand to the right by the number of
  >   places specified in the second operand. The bits filled in on the left
  >   depend on the sign bit of the original operand, in order to preserve
  >   the sign of the result. If the first operand is positive, the result
  >   has zeros placed in the high bits; if the first operand is negative,
  >   the result has ones placed in the high bits. Shifting a value right
  >   one place is equivalent to dividing by 2 (discarding the remainder),
  >   shifting right two places is equivalent to integer division by 4, and
  >   so on.
- `<<` is the Bitwise Left Shift with Sign Operator:

  > It moves all bits in its first operand to the left by the number of
  >   places specified in the second operand. New bits are filled with
  >   zeros. Shifting a value left by one position is equivalent to
  >   multiplying by 2, shifting two positions is equivalent to multiplying
  >   by 4, etc.
- `^` is the Bitwise XOR Operator:

  > It performs a Boolean exclusive OR operation on each bit of its
  >   integer arguments. Exclusive OR means that either operand one is true
  >   or operand two is true, but not both.

Information about binary operators taken from [List of all binary operators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122293/list-of-all-binary-operators-in-javascript) and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_operators.htm.

Note that binary operators truncate floating-points.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the shift operators truncate floating-points before shifting.

Comment: You have a typo **0^'20' === 20 ('02' coerced into 2)** should be **0^'20' === 20 ('20' coerced into 20)**