# JavaScript Adding Booleans

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(true+true); //2
console.log(typeof(true+true)); //number
console.log(isNaN(true+true)); //false
```

Why is adding together 2 boolean types yielding a number? I kind of understand that if they didn't equal (1/0 (binary?)) it would be awkward to try to perform arithmetic on a boolean type, but I can't find the reasoning behind this logic.

Comment: Because they get converted into numbers `Number(true) + Number(true) === 2`

Comment: Because `true` is 1 when auto-converted to a number. Javascript's dynamic type system in action.

Comment: I'd assume the + operand will auto-typecast the values that are being 'merged', resulting in true being treated as a numeric?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but why?

Comment: `+` is doing the casting there.

Comment: Because you can't add booleans, so it converts them to numbers first.

Comment: So would this apply to any other operator?

Comment: Because Javascript was made that way. Trying to convert types so that it fits. It was a design decision the creator later regretted, but it was meant to be a simple scripting language at first... so he built in some "automation" for the basic types.

Comment: Sure... `true/true === 1`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555155/why-is-the-answer-42

Comment: Any operator that will convert its operands to Number types will do this.

Comment: ^^ Right, try `true-true` or `true*true`, they will be treated as ones. You can also cast to string, ie: `true+''+true == "truetrue"`

Comment: **"JavaScript Coercion Demystified"** - http://webreflection.blogspot.de/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Comment: This is very good information. Thank you guys

Comment: LOL true + true = 2... never in my life!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works like that because that's how it's specified to work.

EcmaScript standard specifies that unless either of the arguments is a string, the `+` operator is assumed to mean numeric addition and not string concatenation. Conversion to numeric values is explicitly mentioned:

> Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber( lprim) and ToNumber(rprim).

(where `lprim` and `rprim` are the primitive forms of the left-hand and the right-hand argument, respectively)

EcmaScript also specifies the `To Number` conversion for booleans clearly:

> The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false.

Hence, `true + true` effectively means `1 + 1`, or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language, because you don't have to specify what type something is when you start, like `bool x` or `int i`. When it sees an operation that can't really be done, it will convert the operands to whatever they need to be so that they can have that operation done on them. This is known as type coercion. You can't add booleans, so Javascript will cast the booleans to something that it can add, something like a string or a number. In this case, it makes sense to cast it to a number since 1 is often used to represent true and 0 for false. So Javascript will cast the `true`'s to `1`s, and add them together

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is loosely typed, and it automatically converts things into other things to fit the situation. That's why you can do `var x` without defining it as an `int` or `bool`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6974wx4d(v=vs.94).aspx