# Why does true+true+true===3 resolve to true in javascript

Tags: javascript

The title is sort of self-explanatory, I couldn't find a similar question or explanation for this

Comment: because `true`, when coerced into a number, is `1`.

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555321/javascript-adding-booleans