# why this combination gives me this return. Need explanation

Tags: javascript

when I console this combination of logical NOT and empty array ![]+!![]+!![] it returns 2.

```js
console.log(![]+!![]+!![])
```

Comment: See this [javascript-adding-booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555321/javascript-adding-booleans)

Comment: `[]` is an empty array, which is a truthy value. `!` negates a value. So we have `false + true + true`. The `+` operator converts its operands, to numbers if possible or to strings if not. `false` converts to `0`, `true` converts to `1`. Thus: 2.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder I got this now

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(![]+!![]+!![])`

⬇️

`console.log(false+true+true)`

⬇️

`console.log(0+1+1)`

⬇️

`console.log(2)`

```js
console.log(![] + !![] + !![])
```