# What is the "<<" operator in js?

Tags: javascript, operators

There is use of the "<<" in some code I am reading and I haven't been able to find any documentation on what exactly it does. I assume it is some bit wise function of some sort.

```
console.log(4<<3); 
//This prints out 32.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Arithmetic Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122293/list-of-all-binary-operators-in-javascript

Comment: Huh... the stack overflow search didn't pick up any search results. I even just plainly searched "<< javascript" and other variations of that with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_%28Left_shift%29):

> **Left shift `a << b`**
>
> Shifts `a` in binary representation `b` (`< 32`) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.

Comment: Juhana, VisioN thanks for the edits, looks a lot better :)