# negating self invoking function? !function ($) { ... }(window.jQuery);

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, negate, self-invoking-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I was looking through the Twitter Bootstrap JavaScript code and I noticed all their plugins are wrapped in negating self invoking functions.

I am aware that `function ($) { ... }(window.jQuery);` invokes the function immediately.

But what is the `!` for?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Comment: `function ($) { ... }(window.jQuery);` ...does *not* invoke the function immediately. It introduces a SyntaxError, which is why you need the `!` *(or any operator that will cause the function to be interpreted as part of an expression)*.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to take into account how I normally wrap it in (), which I now know is the same as !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) if you just do:

```
function () { /* ... */ }();
```

You will get an error.
JS will not allow you to fire off a function declaration (because of a concept of "variable hoisting", which isn't technically correct, but is much easier for a lot of people to think about).
If you use declarative functions:

```
function myFunc () { /* ... */ }
```

The JS engine will create them in the scope you're in, before creating the variables of the scope -- even if the vars are all on the top and the functions are all on the bottom.

So when you write:

```
function myFunc () { /* ... */ }();
```

There's an error there, because the vars which don't even exist yet, in the current scope might be called inside, which is a guaranteed crash.

To further that, if you don't give your function-declaration a name:

```
function () { /* ... */ }
```

...then there's an error there, regardless, because you can't call the function yet, but you have no way of getting at it, because it doesn't have a name, and you didn't assign it to a variable.

Operators like `()` or `+` or `!` -- anything which will force the engine to evaluate whatever comes next, will allow you to fire the function like:

```
+function () { /* ... */ }();
```

As long as there is no variable listening for a return statement, you're fine.

2) Additionally, in the case of `!function () { /*...*/ }();`, if that function doesn't have a return statement naturally, then it will return `undefined`.
The opposite of `undefined` is `true` when coerced in that way...

...so if you really, REALLY wanted, you could do something like:

```
var success = !function () { /* ... */ }();
if (success) { doStuff(); }
```