# Confusion about anonymous function declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance

guys i want to know is there any different between this anonymous :

first :

```
(function(){
   //statements
})();
```

second :

```
(function(){
   //statements
}());
```

third :

```
!function(){
   //statmeents
}();
```

i need a clear explanation about this , thanks all :D

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one and only difference is that the last variation uses fewer bytes.

All three use the language's syntax rules to force the `function` to be a *function expression* (which can be immediately invoked) rather than a *function declaration* (which cannot be invoked, must be named, and is subject to *hoisting*).