# Why do Bootstrap functions start with a + sign?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed a + sign preceeding a function in the bootstrap.js code and wondered what effect this has or is it just for fun?

[image: twitter bootstrap]

Comment: Ugh... pictures of text. Mind if I edit it to just text?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn no need, it's a duuuuuuupe.

Comment: The answer also seems to be located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Comment: the plus operator coerces the expression to its right into a number. if there is a "([args])" after the function statement, then the whole thing becomes an expression (instead of a syntax error). the function is then executed to return a value that it then attempts to coerce into a number. if that doesn't work, no error is shown, so it "works" fine. a paren is much more readable...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it forces the parser to treat the part following the `+` as an expression. You can also read [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Also check [JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name)