# Difference between using void vs wrapping in parens for IIFE void function() vs (function())

Tags: javascript, iife

The common practise for creating modules is to wrap them in parens so you won't leak any variables outside of the module (when concatenating etc).

There is also `void` operator, which evaluates a given expression and returns `undefined`. (See on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void%20MDN))

**I wonder what is the reason behind preferring wrapping functions in parens instead of using `void`. Is it historical, is it something related to concatenation, else?**

I know that you can have problems with concatenation when one of the files has a missing a semicolon, leading to nasty problems till you notice it.

### Examples

Say, module1.js (notice the missing comma):

```
(function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module1. I should not be called');
    };
})()
```

and, module2.js:

```
(function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module2. I should not be called either');
    };
})();
```

If you concat these scripts into a bundle, it will produce this:

```
(function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module1. I should not be called');
    };
})()(function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module2. I should not be called either');
    };
})();
```

Since both modules(files) return a function, the second supposedly IIFE becomes an invocation of the *return value of the first module*, effectively calling `console.log`. The common workaround for this is to declare your module with `!(function (){})();` which forces the returned value to be a boolean.

If however, you were to use `void`, like:

```
void function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module1. I should not be called');
    };
}()
```

The concatenated file will still be wrong, but you will notice the error on the first run, therefore more easily noticed. See below.

```
void function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module1. I should not be called');
    };
}()void function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('module2. I should not be called either');
    };
});
```

This throws `Unexpected token void`. As fas as the modules are concerned, I believe `!(function(){}()` and `void function(){}()` achieve the same effect. But I feel like `void` looks more clean (subjective) than wrapping a function with params and prepending `!` to it.

*I am missing something? Wouldn't it be better if we used `void`?*

Comment: The proper solution to your problem is to put the semicolon where it belongs, not to choose a different module header.

Comment: @Bergi You're missing the entire point of the OP!  He is specifically *trying* to make code more robust to potential human errors, and your solution is, "well, just don't make any errors"?!  The only way to guarantee no errors is to do nothing.  We *all* make errors, and need to find ways to design safety into the process.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: I linter/stylechecker/etc could find such mistakes as well and guarantee (as a part of your build process) that they don't happen. Or we could blame the "bundle" concatenation script whose responsibility it actually is to take care of these things. I believe that such setting things up properly is better style than to take mostly unnecessary precautions in each and every file - and that's probably also the reason why these things (`void …`, [`;(…)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1873983/1048572), [`!…`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5827290/1048572)) never took off.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24067605/1048572). So "*Wouldn't it be better if we used `void`?*" could also be answered with "there are simpler ways to reach the same goal".

Answer (score 5):

Well, many JavaScript programmers think `void` is confusing and redundant, especially Douglas Crockford who calls it one of the ["Bad Parts"](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html) of JavaScript.

Preceding a function definition with `void` can be especially confusing. In languages like C++, it means "This is a type of function that doesn't return a value." In JavaScript, `void` doesn't define anything; instead it evaluates the function (or other expression) and returns the value `undefined`. So you don't see it much in JavaScript code.

For more info on using `!` to precede modules, check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123005/3345375).

Also make sure to read [Ben Allman's original blog post on IIFE's](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: As you said, it is *typically* better not to use `void`.  But I feel as if this is the exception that proves the rule:  here, `void` will *in effect* not return a value, since the value `undefined` is immediately discarded.  So, in this case, wouldn't it be *better* to use `void`?  It seems to me that this case even follows the logic intrinsic behind Crockford's original issue with it.  Unless I am missing something... and there's **lots** to miss, when it comes to odd Javascript behaviors.

Comment: Usually an IIFE doesn't return a value anyway. No need to void it. But if you *want* it to return a value, then do this: `var valueFromIIFE = (function() { return "This value"; })();` In other words, you'd need to include a return statement *and* assign the returned value to a variable. And if that's the case, then you *don't* want to turn your nice shiny new returned value into undefined.