# Using void in iife

Tags: javascript

How this works?

```
void function() {}()
```

I saw an explanation that void transforms the iife from declaration to expression, and every expression must be evaluated, is this right?

Thanks.

Comment: What you've shown is not an IIFE - nothing is invoked here.

Comment: I've updated the question @Bergi.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828348/difference-between-using-void-vs-wrapping-in-parens-for-iife-void-function-vs)

Answer (score 0):

When using an immediately-invoked function expression, void can be used to force the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a declaration. Check this link at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

Comment: Is `var x = void function() { return 1; } ()` valid and if yes, does it assign 1 or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

> When using an immediately-invoked function expression, void can be used to force the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a declaration.

Readup:  [`void` operator - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)