# What benefit you will get if add ; or ! at beginning of the javascript file

Tags: javascript

I saw sometime people add ; or ! at the beginning of the javascript file, but wonder what benefits you will get.

```
;(function (_global, _other) {
    "use strict";
    var _global = GLOBAL || {};
    _global.thisModule = _global.thisModule || {};
    var _this = _global.thisModule;

    _this.remove = function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== "string" || !value) {
            return value;
        }

        return value.replace(_other.balabala, '');
    };
}(GLOBAL || {}, GLOBAL.OTHER));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/whats-the-purpose-of-starting-semi-colon-at-beginning-of-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do

Comment: See relevant answer in a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1873999/3716159

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: See [JavaScript Bang “!” Functions vs Leading Semi-Colon “;” IIFEs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24067605/1048572) which lays out the differences