# Why use `!function()` declarations?

Tags: javascript

In [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/client/core.js) you'll find lots of function declerations like the following:

```
!function(undefined){
    var __e = null, __g = null;
    // more code
}
```

Or this one:

```
!function(){
  try {
    var iter = [1].keys();
    iter['return'] = function(){ DANGER_CLOSING = false; };
    Array.from(iter, function(){ throw 2; });
  } catch(e){ /* empty */ }
}();
```

What is the purpose of the negation?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Comment: [JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698/1903116)