# !function in javascript, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

I see this syntax of fb pixel code:

```
!function(...){
   // code
}(...);
```

I don't know what is this syntax to do, can anyone tell me?

Comment: This is a self invoked function and it indicates the false of function's return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Comment: @ManishJangir — "it indicates the false of function's return value" — No, it doesn't. While it does convert the return value to a boolean and invert it, the value is immediately discarded. That isn't what it is used for in that context.

Comment: it's just convertation of statement to expression, same as `(function(){})()`