# Why is there a 0 in an anonymous JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

Have seen many usage in this format:

```
(0, function(a, b){console.log(a + b)})(3, 4)
```

What is `0` for?

Comment: `function(a, b){console.log(a + b)}(3,4)` is not a valid syntax. That's why the author of that code used comma expression to call it. Author would have written the same code like, `(function(a, b){console.log(a + b)})(3,4)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but `(function(a, b){console.log(a + b)})(3,4)` is valid

Comment: It's just another IIFE syntax. I also don't understand why the author chose to use a comma

Answer (score -1):

That `0` is ignored.

That comma is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Basically that `0` is evaluated as `0` then that function expression is evaluated and since the function is the last thing evaluated in the comma list a function reference to it is returned. It is that returned function that is called.

In the code in your question, the `0` is therefore completely useless.

However, it could be that the author intended this instead:

```
0,function(a, b){console.log(a + b)}(3, 4);
```

Which saves typing two characters `(` and `)` but then it takes two characters anyway so it's not very useful.

Answer (score -1):

It serves the same purpose as a [parenthesis or a bang prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax).

`0` is an expression that has no effect. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) puts the right hand side into experssion context.

This means that `function` is then treated as the start of a function *expression* (which can be an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) instead of a function declaration (which would throw an error if you tried to treat it as an IIFE, which this code does by following it with `(3, 4)`).