# Statement evaluation order

Tags: javascript

I have came across `!function() {}();` statement in an on-line test. By changing it to `!function() { return true; }();` I figured out that the function calls before `!`. I assumed that an anonymous function declaration becomes a function expression first, then it invokes, finally a result is logically negated. Is my assumption correct, why does the statement evaluate in this order?

Comment: `!` is an operator and putting that in front of a function or variable will use the value of the rhs and negate it. So the execution happens from the expressed function as soon as (); this is invoked and the value is negated.
so if you had `console.log(function(){return true;}())` would log  `false`  and `console.log(function(){return false;}())` would log `true` and 
`console.log(function(){}())` would log `true`

Comment: What other order could make sense?

Comment: @Nilesh The initial statement is not inside the console.log() function, it makes a difference. If I put it in a browser console it returns _true_, on the other hand `function(){return true;}()` complains about SyntaxError. Could you explain why is it so?

Comment: I don't get where your assumption and the observed behaviour deviate? Both are correct: the function is called before the result is negated.

Comment: @Bergi I can not understand why `function() {}();` invokes a function. Does it become a function expression, how does it deffer from '(function() {})();`?

Comment: You appear to be confusing parser rules and operator precedence with evaluation order.  They're completely orthogonal.

Comment: @AndriySimonov `function(){}` is a function and `()` is an invocation. Why it becomes a function expression, instead of a declaration followed by a syntax error, depends on the parser grammar and has nothing to do with the evaluation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript function leading bang ! syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5827290/1048572) (I'd have closed it but already have voted as unclear)

Comment: @Bergi The question really seems to be confusing. What would be a correct question to ask? Should I delete this one?

Comment: I guess if your confusion is gone now, it would be best to delete it. If there's still something unclear, you might want to ask something like "*Why do `!function(){}()` and `(function(){})()` invoke a function while `function(){}()` is a syntax error?*"; However I guess that would quickly get closed as a duplicate of the question I linked (or one of the many similar ones)

Answer (score 1):

To negate some `x` you need to know what this `x` is. you can't negate an expression, only the result of that expression.

In other words: you can't say "give me the negative of 'set x to the value of y'" `!(x = y)` (well, you *can* write this in JS, but that's a different expression), but you can say "give me the negative of the result of 'does x equal y?'" `!(x == y)`.

The same thing happens with the method. because you call it (using the parentheses), it has to first check what that results in, before beeing able to negate it

**edit:**

As this seems to confuse people: using parentheses tells JavaScript to invoke that function, when they are after the function-definition. try this:
`var test = function(){return 'hello';}`
test will now be the function itself, and running `test()` will return `hello` (a.k.a parentheses make JS call the function)

when you write `var test = function(){return 'hello';}()` instead, you now tell JS to instantly call that function, and whatever that function results in should be the value of `test`. running this will make `test` have the value `'hello'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation about negation makes perfect sense to me, but still it is not clear why `function() {}();` invokes. As far as I understand it is a function declaration with parenthesis as opposed to `(function() {})();` where we have a function expression.

Comment: No, the `function() {}` is a function declaration. the `()` behind that tell Javascript to call that function

Comment: What is the difference between `function() {}()` and `(function() {})()` then? The former throws a SyntaxError in a console.

Comment: see my updated comment. you can't really use the former one on it's own, because it's not valid JS. you CAN however write `(function (){})();` because you then force JS to evaluate `function (){}` first (which is a valid function) before calling it

Comment: I would assume that JS just doesn't know what to do if you just throw it a function-definition without any context. But if you give it an expression (like: call that function, or make test the result of that function), it can work with that

Comment: The point is that `function(){}` can be both an expression or a declaration. Only the context in which it is parsed decides what it is.