# How to make function be called instantly, then be called every 5000ms

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function which updates every 5000ms. However, when I load the page, it waits 5000ms then calls the function for the first time and then waits 5000ms to update it again and again.

I want to make it so, on page load, it instantly calls the function the first time and then waits 5000ms to call it again and again. How can I do this?

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "js works";
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!function` [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) syntax with `setTimeout`:

```js
!function refresh () {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = Date.now()
  setTimeout(refresh, 5000)
}()
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Further reading for those who haven't seen this pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827290/javascript-function-leading-bang-syntax

Comment: What is reason for `!` before function?

Comment: When using `!` Before a function declaration, it becomes a function expression, so you can call it as if you were executing a function expression. You can see it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function#5654929.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout` with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
(function loop() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "js works";
  console.log(new Date().getTime());
  setTimeout(loop, 5000); // Run the loop function for every 5000 ms.
}()); // Run the loop function at first time.
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {

  (function loop() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "js works";
    console.log(new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(loop, 5000);
  }());

}());
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```