# jQuery code to add/remove classes and change display not working?

Tags: jquery, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering a bit of jQuery code I found that does EXACTLY what I want. It is supposed to change the thumbnail in #featured-navigation that's been clicked on to `class="selected"` while the others that are not clicked are just `class=""`. 
It's also supposed to change the connected post (same id as the thumbnail's href) in #featured-post to `style="display: block;"` while the others are `style="display:none;"`.

I know enough about jQuery to know that it's simple, but I don't know enough to know how it works and how I'm supposed to use it. Yeeeeah, I'm just about clueless on jQuery.

So here's my jQuery, which is being called in the footer-

```
/* Featured Rotation */

var featuredContainer = $('div#featured-post > div');
featuredContainer.hide().filter(':first').show();

$('div#featured-navigation > a').click(function () {

    featuredContainer.hide();
    featuredContainer.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div#featured-navigation > a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;

}).filter(':first').click();
```

And this is my whole featured post code that is showing up properly (minus most of the finer styling, as of right now), but is not being affected by the jQuery. I think I have the divs and all set up right, but it's still not working... -

```
<div id="featured-navigation">
<?php
$featuredPostThumbs = new WP_Query();
$featuredPostThumbs->query('showposts=4&cat=9');
while ($featuredPostThumbs->have_posts()) : $featuredPostThumbs->the_post(); ?>
<a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href=
<?php if( $featuredPostThumbs->current_post == 0 ) : ?>
"#featured-first"
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPostThumbs->current_post == 1 ) : ?>
"#featured-second"
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPostThumbs->current_post == 2 ) : ?>
"#featured-third"
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPostThumbs->current_post == 3 ) : ?>
"#featured-fourth"
<?php endif; ?> >
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured_thumb' ); ?>
</a>

<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div id="featured-post" class="clearfix">
<?php

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=4&cat=9');
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<?php if( $featuredPosts->current_post == 0 ) : ?>
<div id="featured-first" style="display: block;">
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPosts->current_post == 1 ) : ?>
<div id="featured-second" style="display: none;">
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPosts->current_post == 2 ) : ?>
<div id="featured-third" style="display: none;">
<?php endif; 
if( $featuredPosts->current_post == 3 ) : ?>
<div id="featured-fourth" style="display: none;">
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="featured-left">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured' ); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<div id="featured-right">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<!-- by <?php the_author() ?> -->
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

And this is my test site, where I'm fiddling with all that. There's lots of unfinished stuff on there right now, but all I need help with for now is getting this jQuery to work.
[test.glutenfreemakeupgal.com/](http://test.glutenfreemakeupgal.com/)

Thank you SO much in advance!

Comment: Does your javascript come after `<div id="featured-navigation">`?

Comment: It does, yes. It's in the footer, in a functions.js file that's being called there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the helpful replies, I finally figured it out! And it's WORKING!! Here's the new complete contents of my functions.js-

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Featured Rotation */

var featuredContainer = $('div#featured-post > div');
featuredContainer.hide().filter(':first').show();

$('div#featured-navigation > a').click(function () {

    featuredContainer.hide();
    featuredContainer.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div#featured-navigation > a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;

}).filter(':first').click();

});
}(jQuery));
```

I found the weird opening tags in this answer here- [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document) I don't 100% get why they had to do this, but it does seem to work just fine.

Thank you again, y'all!! As soon as I get to 15 rep I'll be upping your answers, because they were super duper helpful. I've been struggling to figure this out for days and you finally got me to the place where I could. Thank you! You ROCK!! :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery needs to be placed inside the a call to $(document).ready.  Otherwise, you're trying to bind click events to elements that may not have been created yet.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var featuredContainer = $('div#featured-post > div');
  featuredContainer.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $('div#featured-navigation > a').click(function () {

    featuredContainer.hide();
    featuredContainer.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div#featured-navigation > a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;

  }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Comment: I had a call to $document.ready at the top of my functions.js, but not exactly like that. When I tried it, it gave me an error saying "undefined $ function" or something like that. So I did a little research on the new error and- presto! Found the solution! Thank you so much, you put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I get a script error in `functions.js`: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$')`.

It looks like you messed up with overriding the jQuery `$`. Did you take a look at the jQuery doc about the `$`? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I had not read that and honestly didn't even know about it... Ha! But I'm using a WP site, which apparently loads jQuery in a noConflict anyway? I don't know, that's what I read. I tried a noConflict, but it still pulled up an error about the jQuery `$`. However, your answer put me on the right track!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't forget to accept one of the answers.