# Unable to remove the "view" of a model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

In my view, i have a click event called clear to remove both model, and element from the page.. to use this in my view i have the function like this:

```
define(["backbone","../router/router"], function(Backbone,router){

    "use strict"

    var appView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:"li",
        template:_.template($("#listTemp").html()),
        events:{
            "click" : "clear"
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render:function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },
        listTrigger:function(){
            var studentName = this.model.get("name");
            router.navigate("#/list/" + studentName);

        },
        clear:function(){
            this.model.clear(); // i am triggering models clear method here..
        }
    });

    return  appView;

})
```

in my model i have the method and clearing the modle and element..

```
define(["jquery","underscore","backbone"], function($,_,Backbone){

    "use strict"

    var appModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log(this.view);
        },
        clear:function(){
            this.destroy(); //it works..
            this.view.remove(); // but it throw the error;
        }
    });

    return appModel;

});
```

the error i am getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined model.js:11
Backbone.Model.extend.clear model.js:11
Backbone.View.extend.clear appView.js:24
b.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
v.handle
```

why this 'undefined' - i am getting here.. how to solve it.. can any one help me..?

Comment: You might need to make a different function for this.
Also check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document

Comment: so, it mean should i need to call like this: $this.view.remove();

Comment: Question: What's the purpose of creating a circular reference btw your view and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initiated my view in my appView -

```
    initialize:function(){
                this.render();
                this.model.view = this;
            },
    remove:function(){
            $(this.el).remove(); //removing element
        },
```

works fine. thanks for all.