# jQuery: TypeError 'undefined'is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm just starting out with jQuery and I'm stuck on a basic example. 
I'm using Safari for this example.

01.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.poem-stanza').addclass('highlight');

});
```

first.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Through the Looking-Glass</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/01.css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="01.js"></script>
</head>
    <h1>Through the looking-Glass</h1>
    <div class="author">by Lewis Caroll</div>
    <div class="chapter" id="chapter-1">
        <h2><class="chapter-title">1. Looking-Glass House</h2>
        <p>There was a book lying near Alice on the table, and while she sat watching the White Kind (for she was still a little anxious about him, in case he fainted again), she turned over the leaves, to find some part that she could read, <span class="spoken">"&mdash;for it's all in some language I don't know,"</span> she said to herself.</p>
        <p>It was like this.</p>
        <div class="poem">
            <h3><class="poem-title">YKCOWREBBAJ</h3>
            <div class="poem-stanza">
                <div>Sevot yhtils eht dna ,gillirb sawT'</div>
                <div>;ebaw eht ni elbmig dna eryg diD</div>
                <div>, sevogorob eht erew ysmim llA</div>
                <div>.ebargtuo shtar emom eht dnA</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>She puzzled over this for some time, but at last a bright thought struck her. <span class="spoken">"Why, it's a looking-glass book, of course! And if I hold it up against a glass, the words will al go the right way again."</span></p>
        <p>This as the poem that Alice read.</p>
        <div class="poem">
            <h3 class="poem-title">JABBERWOCKY</h3>
              <div class="poem-stanza">
                    <div>'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves</div>
                    <div>Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;</div>
                    <div>All mimsy were the borogoves,</div>
                    <div>And the mome raths outgrabe.</div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Safari webdevelopment kit, I get the error "jQuery: TypeError 'undefined'is not a function" returned on .addclass('highlight'), and it seems to fail to run the .js I requested.

Can somebody enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong here!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive, `addclass` is different than `addClass`.

Comment: try to use a better editor as I don't no which one you're using I advise to use WebStorm from jetbrains. good luck

Comment: @Abderrazakk Did he mention what editor he is using?

Comment: @wared Thanks I changed that, didn't actually know that JS was case-sensitive.. So much to learn ;). Changed it, but it didn't gave me any results though.

Comment: @Abderrazakk, I'm actually using TextMate as a editor, but I will look into WebStorm, thanks!

Comment: @jumpingcode no but using an editor with code completion for a person starting with new technology, in my opinion, is something which'll help more ! don't you !

Comment: Do you still get the error "jQuery: TypeError 'undefined'is not a function"?

Comment: @HansR83 Just a heads up, you have to pay for WebStorm.

Comment: Thanks guys, actually used AddClass at first, and addClass afterwards. The last one worked.. Thanks for the fast responses! Loving this site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addclass()` should be `addClass()`

Answer (score 1):

You  need to use `addClass('highlight')` not `addclass('highlight')`, notice it's camel case and not lower case.

Furthermore, I believe that this isn't the primary reason for your error and it may be that in your script you have to replace `$` with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('div.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');

});
```

***[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)***

Comment: While you're correct, I don't think that is the bigger issue as you would get `unrecognised function 'addclass'`

Comment: Or may be **`Object [object Object] has no method 'addclass'`**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know. I'm adding to my answer currently for other checks. That part is just the first part I noticed incorrect.

Comment: @palaѕн yeah that too :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');

});
```