# Numbering all classes of the same type on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets assume we have the following code:

```
<a class="addproduct 151">product info</a>
<a class="addproduct 151">product info</a>
<a class="addproduct 151">product info</a>
<a class="addproduct 151">product info</a>
<a class="addproduct 151">product info</a>
```

I want to be able to count how many of the same class is in the page. Then upon clicking a specific one, it tells me which one it is... so... if I click the 3rd one down it will print a "3" to the console.

I've got this code so far:

```
$("addproduct 151").each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass('number' + index);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You can use `eq()` to determine the index of an element, or DOM traversal to get to related elements within. Incremental identifiers are never the best plan.

Comment: Oh perfect, see I'm learning now, I didn't know this before. Can you let me know how this code would look for the wanted result?

Comment: Add a click handler for the elements, and put `console.log($(this).eq());` in it.

Comment: Should the numbering be page wide or within their immediate parent node?

Comment: If you're trying to create a relationship between your `A` elements, and a dataset, I'd suggest using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead of trying to find an ID based on the element's offset in the DOM. Ex: `<a class="addproduct 151" data-id="1">product info</a>`. Then grab that data attribute in your click handler `var id=$(this).data('id');`.

Comment: I can't edit the page, this all have to be unobtrusive. I'm trying to create variables to place in google analytic tags. When the specific link is clicked I need to send a "1" "2" "3" etc to google analytics.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did what you said but I'm stupid when it comes to new code. I have this: $('.addproduct.151').click(function() {
console.log($(this).eq());
}); I still don't know how to print out which one is clicked onto the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `length` and `index` to get those numbers

```
var elems = $(".addproduct.151")

elems.on('click', function() {

    var total    = elems.length;
    var this_one = elems.index(this);

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xTPC8/)

Comment: I keep getting "undefined is not a function" with all of these options

Answer (score 0):

Use `index()` if it has a parent.

```
$('#parentDiv a').on('click',function(){
    var thisNumber = $(this).index();
    console.log(thisNumber);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSk98/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as it is originally worded "if I click the 3rd one down" which I interpret as the 3rd element with that class anywhere on the page regardless of parentage:

```
$('.product').on('click', function(e) {
  var products = $('.product').toArray();
  var id = products.indexOf(this);
  console.log(id);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4NJT/1/

Note: The index starts at 0, so if you want to print out "3", you'd have to print index+1;

Comment: Thankyou for your response, it works great on fiddle. I'm just unsure why when I use it on my site I get a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" Just frustrating. I guess I'll have to figure this one out. Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is you're trying to use the variable `$` as a function before it's been defined as one ... did you put this code in a script block that occurs before you include jquery.js ? You can duplicate the error via: `var x = undefined; x();` . Also maybe look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document