# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function when working with sliders with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get the error when working with jQuery.js.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#defaultslide1').slider')
```

I did my homework before asking this question. I tried suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document) and also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document):

such as using `jQuery(document);` instead of `$(document);` or defining it as

`var $ =jQuery.noConflict();` but none work.

Some background:

I'm using Bootstrap 3. I have the following in the head:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and this in the body:

```
 <div id="content">                                    
    <div id="defaultval">
      Price Value: <span id="currentval">50</span>
    </div>
    <div id="defaultslide1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
      $('#defaultslide1').slider({ 
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      value: 50,
      slide: function(e,ui) {
      $('#currentval').html(ui.value);
      }
    });
   </script>
 </div>
```

The text shows up but not the slider.

Comment: Seems like a css problem????

http://jsfiddle.net/HvE3Z/2/

No javascript errors on that fiddle, probably css

Comment: Hmm...the CSS conflicts with bootstrap CSS. Is there no way to keep Bootstrap's CSS and yet have the sliders?

Comment: It sounds to me like there might be more than one copy of jQuery... check the networking tab of the browser's development tools.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound  CSS won't cause a javascript error

Comment: @charlietfl, I made a JSFIddle, with no js errors.  The bar not appearing must be CSS...

Comment: at the end of the script you missed `});`. indent your code to make your code readable and see this errors.