# Display table cell content in tooltip (jsfiddle won't work on real site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to have the full table cell content show as a tooltip. This will let visitors see the part that is hidden since it is too long to fit in the cell.

I am attempting the solution described here (please look there to see expected behavior):
http://jsfiddle.net/zWfac/

```
var container = $("#container");

$("td").hover(function ()
          {
              container.children(".tooltip").remove(); 

              var element = $(this);
              var offset = element.offset();
              var toolTip = $("<div class='tooltip'></div>");

              toolTip.css(
                  {
                      top : offset.top,
                      left : offset.left
                  });

              toolTip.text(element.text());
              container.append(toolTip);
          });
```

I changed the container var definition from an id to a class:

```
var container = $(".sortTable");
```

I added the code to our wordpress site by putting it right before `</body>` in my child theme's footer.php, inside a `jQuery().ready(function()` block.

I am getting an error that leads me to think jQuery is not properly initializing but I am too new to this language to be able to troubleshoot effectively. I'd appreciate any suggestions on this.

I have a sample table on this page:
http://frugalmule.com/overflow/

Please note my client previously posted a somewhat incomplete question about this which was removed; I have made many changes to the page since then but I still don't have what he needs. Since the error occurs when putting the JSFiddle to the real site, I don't know how to state the problem in any simpler fashion.

Comment: See this question and answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `$` with `jQuery` in your script. This will solve your problem. You can refer this link: http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: That did it! All I had to do was add $ in the ready function to make it work. I thought it would be something simple and related to wordpress but I didn't come up with the answer when I googled for it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't come here that often; how do I 'accept' the answer? Never Mind I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Like that... Thanx... See you...:-)