# jQuery script gives 'undefined is not a function' console error in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This jquery snippet works fine in JSfiddle...

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".link").click(function() {
        jQuery('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
        jQuery('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
```

But when I insert it into the footer of my WordPress site I get the following error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

anyone any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest jQuery is not loaded on your wordpress site.

Comment: Can confirm that jQuery is loaded fine on the site and working correctly

Comment: @fightstarr20 Which line gives the error?

Comment: @fightstarr20 Assuming that the exception is thrown from that context (ie. not inside another function), either `jQuery` or `$` evaluates to undefined or to a non-jQuery value. This is easy to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [7975203](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975203/1992780):

Wordpress uses jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode by default.  You need to
reference it using `jQuery` as the variable name, not `$`, e.g. use

```
jQuery(document);
```

instead of

```
$(document);
```

You can easily wrap this up in a self executing function so that `$`
refers to jQuery again (and avoids polluting the global namespace as
well), e.g.

```
(function ($) {
   $(document);
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: The OP *does* use `$(this).data` - as such, this answer seems relatively sensible. (Unfortunately it's hard to know "for sure" with such an under-specified error/question.)

Comment: You are right, can't believe I missed this one.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jivings reread the question.