# CSS dropdown submenu z-index disappears behind main menu

Tags: css, wordpress, position, z-index, submenu

Asked to help fix the submenu flyout z-index on an old Wordpress theme [Website](http://naega.org). Sub flyouts are behind main dropdown. I have never seen menu code written this way. Any tips? I have tried

```
position: relative;
z-index:99999! important;
```

with little effect.

```html
#menu {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 42px;
}
ul#menu {
 -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

ul#menu li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size: 16px;
 /*text-transform:uppercase; */
 /* letter-spacing: 2px; */
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 color: #fff;

}
ul#menu li {
 -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
ul#menu li li{
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

} 
ul#menu li:hover {
 background-color: #000033;
}
.current_page_item {

}
.current_page_item a{
 color: #fff!important;
}
ul#menu li:hover > a{
 color: #fff;
}
ul#menu li li:hover {
 background-color: #eee;
}
/*
ul#menu li li:hover > a{
 color: #ffffff;
} */
ul#menu li li a{
 color: #bdbdbd;
 background-color: #000033;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight:400;
}
ul#menu li a:active, ul#menu li a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: transparent;
}
ul#menu li li a:active, ul#menu li li a:hover {
 color: #000033!important;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I'd just get rid of all the `z-index`es you can, and start using them from the ground up, using rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you seem to have an uncaught TypeError on the menu.js file, perhaps that could be the issue. See [type errors here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Comment: Good point. I'll take a look. I made a few changes to move the menu to the right and not worry about the z-index. Not perfect at all, still need to remove the translucent box, but a start.                                                           ul#menu li li li{
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 200px;
        float:left;
        left:65px;
}

Comment: If you look closely at the child of the child it aligns with the parent in the very top menu, so at a guess it's absolute position is being set by the upper nav element width.