# Error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

"http://www.roozrang.com"
This is the site which i am trying to develop.
i used "scrollbox jquery" plugin.
You can see in the console window.
It Says-

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

i search this topic in stack and try resolving error with these solutions.
i test "noConflict mode" for JQuery. but this problem exist.
but i guess that this error is different from others.

i am not able to find wt i have done wrong.
why this error occurred?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? Take a minute to read the FAQ on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Answer (score 0):

I got `TypeError: jQuery(...).scrollbox is not a function` error in console when i visited your site. you wrote `jQuery('#news_scroll1').scrollbox({` in document ready, but you don't have DOM element having ID `news_scroll1`

Comment: @mevius Yes it does not, I just pointed out mistake and explained what I got in console.