# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when moved same code to another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have moved my javascript over to another site without modifying it and it should work out of the box as nothing has changed but I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on two instances.

My [first website here](http://peterseabrook.com/galaxias) works fine.

My [second website here](http://peterseabrook.com/galaxias2) does not.

Example with this code as one of the instances but gives me the same error for the same part of code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#clock_sydney').jClocksGMT({offset: '+11'});
            $('#clock_greece').jClocksGMT({offset: '+3'});
        });
    </script>
```

It is telling me there is something wrong with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

On both pieces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is driving me insane.

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Comment: jQuery isn't initialized.

Comment: add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the second page.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi it's already included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your jQuery is in noConflict mode, thus it cant identify `$` symbol
You can use `jQuery()` instead of `$` or wrap your code like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Boom! That did it!
Thanks a bunch champ!

Comment: No only one of them will work at a time whichever one comes first on the page. Got any fixes that Sir?

Comment: @peter-seabrook, make sure u replaced/wrapped both of them, it should work. Alternatively you can place all the code in 1 function.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **jQuery** reference. It is really easy to identify this kind of errors because it said that `$` is undefined and `$` is the var which represent the `jQuery object`.

Just include the respective script in your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```