# jQuery - TypeError: undefined is not a function when searching array

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I'm writing a `onclick` listener for a button but receiving an

> **Uncaught TypeError:** undefined is not a function error on line 4 of this code:

```
$("button#searchKeyword").click(function(){
    var searchTerm = $("input#searchBox").val();
    var i = myArr.indexOf(searchTerm)+1;
    var locationID = myArr[i].value();
    alert(searchTerm + " " + i + " " + locationID );   
});
```

The `locationID` is a 4 or 5 digit integer. And `myArr` is an array of strings and numbers (i.e. `[string, number, string, number...]`).

I've tried adding `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document). But none of the solutions there seem to work for me.

I'm wondering if the problem is a parsing issue? Do I need to parse `i` to an `integer`? If so how would I do that?

Comment: Which line gives the error and what is `myArr[i].value()`? Does your array elements have a method named `value`?

Comment: The fourth line - ("error on line 4 of this code"). `myArr[i].value()` should be the `locationID`. I'm not sure what you mean by your other question.

Comment: I mean the same as answered below. Native objects like strings and numbers that your array contains, don't have a method `value()`. But you call this method on these native elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myArr` is an array of strings and numbers, then you will get the error when you call `myArr[i].value()` because `value` is not defined for either numbers or strings.

You might also have an issue with `i` going beyond the bounds of the array because you add 1 to it. (That shouldn't cause this error message, but it's worth noting)

Comment: How then might I go about getting the value at index `[i]` ?

Comment: Just do `myArr[i]` If you want to convert strings to an integer, then do `parseInt(myArr[i])`

Comment: Ah right, thanks! This answers my question. Didn't realise it'd be that simple.