# Can't get scrollmagic to swipe up 'natural' in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scrollmagic

Running into a problem with the scrollmagic 'section wipes (natural)' activation. What I have in my wordpress theme:

**functions.php**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollMagic' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollMagicPlugin' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollMagicDebug' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'sceneControls' );
```

the scene controller is sceneControls.js and includes

**sceneControls.js**

```
$(function () { // wait for document ready
    // init
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
        globalSceneOptions: {
            triggerHook: 'onLeave'
        }
    });

    // get all slides
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

    // create scene for every slide
    for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: slides[i]
            })
            .setPin(slides[i])
            .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
            .addTo(controller);
    }
});
```

I am receiving console errors however, I may be including **sceneControls.js** in a bad manner.

**Console Readout**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Any thoughts, have tried several variations:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'sceneControls' );
```

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

This was revised. Rnevius after changing the function to a noConflict. The console no longer shows an error but the behaviour is not there.

Comment: Is `$` for jQuery? If so, make sure that you load the script after jQuery. Check the generated HTML source for script tag orders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Comment: This last link solved it rnevius adding in `var $ =jQuery.noConflict();`
just before calling

`$(document).ready(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Per last comment

`var $ =jQuery.noConflict();`
just before calling

`$(document).ready(function () {`