# Jquery Conflict with scroll to element of another page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My domain is:http://princessdannam.com/.
I using two scripts one for datepicker and one for scroll.
This is for datepicker:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Datepicker
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});   
        jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

        jQuery("#booking_form").submit(function() {
            var datepickedup = jQuery("input#datepicker").val();
            var adults = jQuery("#adults option:selected").val();
            var nights = jQuery("#nights option:selected").val();
            window.open("https://www.luxuryroomreservations.com/en-GB/IBE/234/Room/Availability?StartDate="+datepickedup+"&NoOfAdults="+adults+"&NoOfChildren=0&NoOfNights="+nights+"&HotelCode=HUPHHPD", "_blank");
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>

This is for scroll:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.ubermenu-submenu li').find('a').click(function(){
        var $url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var hash = $url.substring($url.indexOf('#')+1);
        var $anchor = jQuery('#'+$url).offset();
        window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top);


        });
    });
</script>
```

When I add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`, then datepicker stopped working, and if I remove this scroll query stopped working and also other pages animation stopped working.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you know $.noConflict()

Comment: there should not be any issue if you don't have references of different versions of jQuery.

Comment: @guvenckardas Yes, I have already used jQuery.noConflict(), but its not worked. I have also used with variable but nothing happened.

Comment: @jai But I'm getting this issue.

Comment: run this in console: `$.fn.jquery` and show the result comming, this will let you see what version of jquery is actually used on the page.

Comment: You used noConflict but I think still using jQuery. You need tou use var x = $.noConflict() and x(datepicker) or etc.

Comment: WordPress already includes jQuery and jQuery-UI. I'm not sure why you're including it again.

Comment: @guvenckardas <script type="text/javascript">
 var x = jQuery.noConflict();
    x(document).ready(function() {
        x('.ubermenu-submenu li').find('a').click(function(){
   var href = x(this).attr('href');
   var anchor = x('#'+href).offset();
   window.scrollTo(anchor.left,anchor.top);
   return true;
  });
    });
</script>              I have updated this jquery, but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document)

Comment: @rnevius  I know but when I remove this jquery, my calander is not working. So, I have included it and added script into footer file.

Comment: @NishaSharma you need to use if for datepicker

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var x = $.noConflict();x(document).ready(function(){x("#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});x( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
x("#booking_form").submit(function() {var datepickedup=x("input#datepicker").val();var adults=x("#adults option:selected").val();var nights = x("#nights option:selected").val();window.open("https://www.luxuryroomreservations.com/en-GB/IBE/234/Room/Availability?StartDate="+datepickedup+"&NoOfAdults="+adults+"&NoOfChildren=0&NoOfNights="+nights+"&HotelCode=HUPHHPD", "_blank");return false;}); });</script>

Comment: @rnevius I have used all the possibilties for this but nothing worked for me. When I use <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        
  $('ul.ubermenu-row').find('a').click(function(){
   var $href = $(this).attr('href');
   var $anchor = $('#'+$href).offset();
   window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top);
   return false;
  });


 });
</script>  It give an error $ is not a function, but my scroll works. But other pages animation or plugins stopped working.

Comment: @guvenckardas I have added that script, now my calander stopped working.

Comment: @NishaSharma could we try on jsfiddle?

Comment: @guvenckardas I have tried on jsfiddle and its working, but not in my site.

Comment: @NishaSharma you can put in github your project and share so we can solve that

Comment: @guvenckardas This is not my project. Its my clients project.

Comment: From jQuery.scrollTo readme : "The plugin requires jQuery 1.8 or higher.".

Comment: @vard I have include script <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.ubermenu-submenu li').find('a').click(function(){
   var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
   var anchor = jQuery('#'+url).offset();
   window.scrollTo(anchor.left,anchor.top);
   return true;
  });
    });
</script> and its working for scroll, but contact page animation or plugins stopped working.

Comment: I see this error in the console on your site: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.