# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function error with Animate It JS file in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm struggling with some javascript here, as I keep getting an error, but no matter what I do, I still get an error - the error is on line 400 (http://www.stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins-events/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/js/css3-animations.js) and as I understand it's something to do with the $ and WordPress (I don't know JS) but I have tried things I have seen on here, such as using document. and jQuery, in replace of the $, but it just brings a different error :/

Can any JS expert point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to edit your question, and include the erroneous code **in the question itself**. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: do you have jQuery library in your site?

Comment: @CláudioBarreira , WordPress includes jQuery by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document

Comment: As stated, I have looked through them, and in places added })(jQuery); and tried jQuery(document) but still get the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is related to the standard wordpress practice of using `jQuery.noConflict()` to prevent collisions with other libraries that use `$`.

Whoever put that code together failed to consider this well documented practice.

You should be able to fix it by wrapping the bottom part of the code in an IIFE wrapper...the same way the upper sections are done:

```
(function($) {

// all code after "//CSS3 Animate-it" on line 399

})(jQuery);
```

Also make sure that jQuery is loaded in page before this particular file is.
It's possible other poor integration practices were used as well

Comment: Wow, perfect. It works like a charm, thank you so much good sir!