# WordPress functions.php and jQuery not linking correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I've been trying to figure out why my jQuery isn't properly working with my custom Wordpress website?

Here's my **functions.php** file

```
<?php 

    function customcode_theme_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('customcode-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    }
    add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customcode_theme_styles');

    function customcode_theme_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script('easing-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('animate-enhanced-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('superslides-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.superslides.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('customcode-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customcode.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customcode_theme_js');

?>
```

Now I am able link my CSS perfectly fine, but anything jQuery isn't properly linking?

Here's the **customcode.js** file I am trying to link my functions.php to:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('nav-scroll');
          } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-scroll');
          }
});
```

Am I missing something? Let me know, any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: so what happens? Is file loading? Errors in console? Likely get `$ not defined` error since wordpress generally uses `noConflict()`

Comment: Your browser console will tell you exactly what the issue is. You'll be able to see that `$` is undefined, and that your scripts are loading correctly.

Comment: Don't need to assume ...look for it in browser dev tools network and look for errors also in console

Comment: I receive this: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Thanks to rnevius http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document This solved the problem!

Comment: So it's something like this? 

    `function CustomFunction() {

      // Your script

    };
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
      CustomFunction();

    }); `