# Why create an anonymous function with a ! before it?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

What's the point of the `!` in the snippet bellow?

```
!function ($) {

   // code

}(window.jQuery);
```

This syntax is used extensively in [Twitter's bootstrap.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html)

Comment: Same question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422585/preceding-function-in-javascript/5422658#5422658).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are calling the function right after the declaration (with window.jQuery as a parameter)

another syntax is:

```
(function ($) {

   // code

})(window.jQuery);
```

some people care more about one character than readability