# what does `!function()` mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a nice [bundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle) that integrates Bootstrap with Symfony. It contains some javascript for dealing with form field collections. When I was looking at the [code](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/blob/develop/Resources/js/bc-bootstrap-collection.js) to see how they did it I ran across this:

```
!function($){

  //function body

}(window.jQuery);
```

I'm familiar enough with javascript to recognize `(function(arg){})(anArg);` as a self-executing function, but since this lacks the enclosing parentheses I'm at a loss as to what `!` is negating.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preceding ! takes the un-parseable statement, and allows it to to be parsed by the JS engine, which in turn returns true.

```
function(){}();
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

!function(){}();
>>true
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422585/preceding-function-in-javascript/5422658#5422658)