# What does the Javascript !function declaration syntax do?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I ran across a [function definition style](https://github.com/ded/emile/blob/master/src/ender.js) that is new to me while browsing the Emile animation library:

```
!function () {
       // do something
}();
```

I'm familiar with:

- Function expressions: `var foo = function (){}`
- Named function expressions: `var foo = function bar(){}`
- Function declarations: `function foo(){}`
- Immediate functions: `var foo = function (){}()` or `var foo = (function (){})()`

The snippet above uses immediate function invocation (for variable scoping, I assume), but the ! is what's throwing me off. JSLint is happy with it, so it must be kosher. What does it do?