# Need help understanding Twitter bootstraps plugins (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I get all of the plugins code except for one line, and due to the way search engines work I cant actually search for my question.

The question is what in the hell is this:

```
(!function($) {/*....*/})(jQuery);
```

Why does it say !functions($)?? I'm guessing for the same effect of the `$.noConflict()` but isn't that why we just use `(function($) {/*...*/})(jQuery);` it just wraps the dollar sign to our function block. I am completely aware that I could be way off base here, I'm still intermediate in jQuery/js.

If someone could please enlighten me on the effect of the NOT operator before the function statement, i would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit**: It would appear that i overlooked bootstrap not having **`(!function($) ... )`** but just being **`!function($)...`**
but you guys helped me in realizing it is just an alternative to ()

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yea check it out http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js

Comment: First result on Google for "exclamation mark function definition javascript" is....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: i.e. seems to be pointless since `()` are used anyway.

Comment: facepalm moment... i didnt even think to write it all the way out... thank you sir!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586870/in-javascript-what-is-the-advantage-of-function-over-function too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there a couple things going on here. Everything is being wrapped in an anonymous function that is executed right away. This is to create a scope for the library so that when the author declares functions and variables they are are not global by default.

With me so far. Ok next thing is the whole `($){...}(jQuery)` thing. What is going on here is the author is passing the `jQuery` library into the anonymous wrapper function as a parameter called `$`. So in the scope of the anonymous function he can use `$` to reference `jQuery` as you would expect. This is more of a best practices thing because 99% of the time jQuery is already defined as `$` in the global scope, but its considered bad form to refer to global variables within a functions scope, and thus he / she passes it in as a parameter.

Still there? The exclamation mark: there is a rule in Javascript that states the first line of a program MUST be an expression (ie not a function declaration aka statement). By prepending the ! the author is turning the declaration into an expression (that returns false). In this case however I don't think the ! is actually required because the declaration is wrapped in () and executed right away. (A function call is an expression)

Comment: Indeed, it's already an expression; the `!` is redundant. It's an _alternative_ to wrapping the declaration in parens, but the author has done both for some reason. And I don't know what you're referring to when you talk about the first line of a program; indeed the vast majority of Javascript scripts I'm sure begin with statements.