# issue with immediately-invoking-functions in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
!function add_them(a,b) { return a+b;} (9,4)
console.log(add_them());
</script>
```

Question:

it shows: ReferenceError: add_them is not defined, what is the problem? and how to make it show the right result: 13?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for the response.. I found that out, so deleted the comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a simple function declaration:

```
function add_them(a,b) { return a+b;}
console.log(add_them(9,4));
```

If you wanted to use an immediately invoked function expression, it might look like this:

```
console.log(function add_them(a,b) { return a+b; } (9,4));
//          \    expression                      / ^^^^^
//                                                 invocation
```

however the identifier (`add_them`) is not reusable outside (after) of the [function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#expr-vs-decl).

Also notice that when your IEFE is supposed to yield some result, the [(little) advantage of !function(){}() over (function () {})()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7586870) is neglected since the result gets negated.

Comment: thanks, why i can not do this way: console.log(!function add_them(a,b) { return a+b; } (9,4)); !function () {}(); will also invoke the function, right?

Comment: @user2294256 The ! operator actually changes the _value_ where the (  just forces it into an expression. You're performing negation on 13 which returns 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the browser (well, it's technically correct according to the spec).

Try another trick to make it treat the function as an expression:

```
(function add_them(a,b) { return a+b;})(9,4) // 13
```

Or simply:

```
console.log((function add_them(a,b) { return a+b;})(9,4)) // logs 13
```

**If you're just trying to fixate the parameters** you can [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to values (which is what it seems to me you're trying to do):

```
var add_them = (function(a,b) { return a+b;}).bind(null, 9,4)
console.log(add_them());// logs 13
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that immediately invoked function expressions are **function expressions**.

In JavaScript functions may be either declarations or expressions. For instance, consider:

```
(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) // This is an expression
 function (a, b) { return a + b; }  // This is a declaration
```

How to distinguish a function expression from a function declaration? If the function is used in place where an expression is expected it automatically becomes an expression. Function expressions can be invoked immediately.

On the other hand a function declaration is also easy to spot because declarations in JavaScript are hoisted. Hence the function can be invoked before it appears in the program. For example, consider:

```
console.log(add(2, 3));

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Now the problem with your code is that you're immediately invoking a function expression. However because it's an expression and not a declaration you can't use it like a normal function. You need to declare a function before you can use it.

Do this instead:

```
add_them(9, 4);

console.log(add_them());

function add_them(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If you want to fix the parameters of the function then you may use `bind` as follows:

```
var add_9_4 = add_them.bind(null, 9, 4);

console.log(add_9_4());

function add_them(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Hope that helps.